# Aliasing github.token in ~/.gitconfig to a shell command

Tags: git, bash, github, git-config

I would like to set the value of github.token in my ~/.gitconfig to be the result of a shell command. I currently have the following:

```
[github]
  user = zmanji
  token = !echo ~/.githubtoken 2> /dev/null
```

However git config github.token does not return the contents of the ~/.githubtoken file but the command itself. How can I get this to work as desired?

Edit: Just to be clear, I am trying to achieve what is implied [here](https://github.com/defunkt/gist):

> You can also define github.token to be a command which returns the actual token on stdout by setting the variable to a command string prefixed with `!`.

Comment: Try `cat` instead of `echo` ?

Comment: @Zameer - I'm no longer convinced that my `cat` answer was correct.  Testing...  (I've deleted my answer until I am sure.)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of storing my GitHub token in a file, I store it in my OS X Keychain and get it like this (snippet from my `.gitconfig`):

```
[github]
  token = !security find-generic-password -gs \"GitHub API Token\" 2>&1 >/dev/null | awk '/password/ {print $2}' | tr -d \\\"
```

Comment: What version of git are you running?

Comment: v1.7.1 (sorry for the delay, I only just saw your question).

Answer (score 2):

It appears the catch here is that he is not setting the token in the gitconfig setting. He is using  [defunkt's hub tool](https://github.com/defunkt/hub). This is a wrapper for the git command which among other things, allows you to have `GITHUB_USER` and `GITHUB_TOKEN` environment variables. Which will override the settings in the local `.gitconfig` file.

Then to make it seamless the user you pointed to aliased `alias git=hub` in his [ZSH config](https://github.com/mattly/dotfiles/blob/master/zsh/50_aliases.zsh).  You should be able to then source a local file where you set your environment variables and push your repository to the public world with all of your private information in tact.

**NOTE for homebrew users on OSX, you can install the tool via `brew install hub`.

Comment: I wasn't trying to use hub. I was trying to get git config to give me a value that I did not explicitly store in the file.

Comment: fair enough, it looked like you were just trying to store the value of the github token outside of the gitconfig so you could put it in a repo of its own (that was my intent when I found this). At any rate, best of luck!

Comment: That's exactly it. Thats why I wanted my gitconfig to give me a value that I did not store in it. That way I could share my entire gitconfig without giving away public information. I think using the environment variables as you suggest will be a better solution in the long term as I can have this functionality in my bash_profile or bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can infer from the [git config man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), only `git config alias.*` has the possibility to define shell commands.

So maybe [defunkt](https://github.com/defunkt) was talking about an alias called token

```
git config alias.token '!security 2>&1 >/dev/null find-generic-password -gs github.token | ruby -e 'print $1 if STDIN.gets =~ /^password: \\\"(.*)\\\"$/''
```

It would be used for quickly getting back the value of his GitHub token.
The return value would be then assigned to `github.token` through a classic `git config github.token xxx`.

Comment: My goal is to have git config github.token return my token without storing it in my .gitconfig. It seems other people are doing this as well: https://github.com/mattly/dotfiles/blob/master/gitconfig#L6 .

Comment: @Zameer and you did try `!sh -c 'echo $GITHUB_TOKEN'` instead of `!echo` directly?

Comment: Yes, the string "!sh -c 'echo $GITHUB_TOKEN'" is returned and not the value of the env variable.

Comment: @Zameer: exactly the result I got on my side. In other words, I am not sure it actually works.

Comment: Can anybody tell me what is `github.token`? I've heard `github.user` but what value does `github.token` have?

Comment: @SantoshKumar As commented in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129232/problem-in-pushing-to-github/7130405#7130405, GitHub no longer use (for non-ssh communication, that is git:// or https:// protocols) plain token, but OAuth 2 token: https://github.com/blog/1270-easier-builds-and-deployments-using-git-over-https-and-oauth: so no need for a `github.token` in your config.