# Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed

Tags: git, github, dvcs

I was able to clone a copy of this repo over HTTPS authenticated. I've made some commits and want to push back out to the GitHub server. Using Cygwin on Windows 7 x64.

```
C:\cygwin\home\XPherior\Code\lunch_call>git push
Password:
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://MichaelDrog
alis@github.com/derekerdmann/lunch_call.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Also set it up with verbose mode. I'm still pretty baffled.

```
C:\cygwin\home\XPherior\Code\lunch_call>set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1

C:\cygwin\home\XPherior\Code\lunch_call>git push
Password:
* Couldn't find host github.com in the _netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to github.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 207.97.227.239... * 0x23cb740 is at send pipe head!
* Connected to github.com (207.97.227.239) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: 2.5.4.15=Private Organization; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US; 1.
3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=California; serialNumber=C3268102; C=US; ST=California; L
=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=github.com
*        start date: 2011-05-27 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: 2013-07-29 12:00:00 GMT
*        subjectAltName: github.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert High Ass
urance EV CA-1
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /derekerdmann/lunch_call.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.7.4.3282.g844cb
Host: github.com
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
< Server: nginx/1.0.4
< Date: Thu, 15 Sep 2011 22:44:41 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 55
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="GitHub"
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Expire cleared
* Connection #0 to host github.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://MichaelDrogalis@github.com/dereker
dmann/lunch_call.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack'
* Couldn't find host github.com in the _netrc file; using defaults
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host github.com
* Connected to github.com (207.97.227.239) port 443 (#0)
* 0x23cb740 is at send pipe head!
* Server auth using Basic with user 'MichaelDrogalis'
> GET /derekerdmann/lunch_call.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
User-Agent: git/1.7.4.3282.g844cb
Host: github.com
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
< Server: nginx/1.0.4
< Date: Thu, 15 Sep 2011 22:44:41 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 55
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="GitHub"
* The requested URL returned error: 401
* Closing connection #0
* Couldn't find host github.com in the _netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to github.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 207.97.227.239... * 0x23cb740 is at send pipe head!
* Connected to github.com (207.97.227.239) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL re-using session ID
* SSL connection using AES256-SHA
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Server certificate:
*        subject: 2.5.4.15=Private Organization; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US; 1.
3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=California; serialNumber=C3268102; C=US; ST=California; L
=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=github.com
*        start date: 2011-05-27 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: 2013-07-29 12:00:00 GMT
*        subjectAltName: github.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert High Ass
urance EV CA-1
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'MichaelDrogalis'
> GET /derekerdmann/lunch_call.git/info/refs HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
User-Agent: git/1.7.4.3282.g844cb
Host: github.com
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache

* The requested URL returned error: 403
* Expire cleared
* Closing connection #0
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://MichaelDrog
alis@github.com/derekerdmann/lunch_call.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

These are the versions of git and curl that I have:

```
C:\Users\XPherior>git --version
git version 1.7.4.msysgit.0

C:\Users\XPherior>curl --version
curl 7.21.7 (amd64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.21.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtsp
smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate Largefile NTLM SSL SSPI libz
```

Comment: Look at the comment, which should be posted as an answer. Made it work with 1.7.1, had the missing User/Password prompt problem, too. Props to http://stackoverflow.com/a/9575906/805284 ...

Comment: check the user has read/write access to the repository

Comment: In the future, don't paste "Authorization: Basic <stuff>" when showing example http headers.  It's easy to base64 decode that and get your password.  @mike:  if you haven't changed your github password since you posted this question, I would suggest you do so.

Comment: @FlipMcF Thanks man. Was unaware. Password changed.

Comment: Note that at least git 1.8 automatically responds to the Forbidden message by prompting for a username, rendering all of this tinkering with remote URLs unnecessary. Thus if you're finding some machines prompt you for credentials and some respond "403 Forbidden," check whether one is using git 1.8 and the other an earlier version.

Comment: I am using "Github for Windows" and had similar issue when switched between two Github accounts. Here's my solution:        
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565876/cannot-access-remote-git-repository/31010578#31010578

Comment: I don't understand, why is this problem happening in the first place?

Comment: In my case my personal access token on github was not setup to grant permission to the repository. Check that `repo  Full control of private repositories` is checked under "Edit personal access token"

Comment: In windows could just be a credentials issue. There is an answer by Andrew Gans below that mentions it. I put the full solution that worked for me from another post in a comment to that answer.

Comment: In my case I was behind a company proxy, which (in some way I can't figure out) caused problems. From my home network I was able to push using the https url without problems. I used this guide to set the remote url: https://github.com/Hervian/aop-logging.git

Comment: See here for a solution: https://janac.medium.com/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed-bcdcb5c0732

Comment: You should tr and follow the steps in this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1064197/how-to-switch-git-user-at-terminal)

Comment: in my case, it was .gitconfig. Make sure you align the username in the .gitconfig to the username in https://github.com/<user_name>/<repo>.git

Answer (score 1008, accepted):

I just got the same problem and just figured out what's cause.

Github seems only supports ssh way to read&write the repo, although https way also displayed 'Read&Write'.

So you need to change your repo config on your PC to ssh way:

1. Edit `.git/config` file under your repo directory.
2. Find `url=`entry under section `[remote "origin"]`.
3. Change it from:
   `url=https://MichaelDrogalis@github.com/derekerdmann/lunch_call.git`
   to:
   `url=ssh://git@github.com/derekerdmann/lunch_call.git`
   That is, change all the texts before `@` symbol to `ssh://git`
4. Save `config` file and quit. now you could use `git push origin master` to sync your repo on GitHub.

Comment: This is often encountered when you clone with the git read-only address (which is the default when you aren't logged in) instead of the read+write ssh address.

Comment: My `.git/config` was more like `url=https://github.com/mynickname/my_repo.git`
But I also changed it like `url=ssh://git@github.com/mynickname/my_repo.git` and it did the trick

Comment: You can change a repo url with `git remote set-url` command. See my answer below.

Comment: or simply change it from the command line using `git remote set-url <name> git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git`

Comment: this problem happened after i switched to using homebrew

Comment: Sorry, but this is a band-aid solution.  SSH is not an option for everybody.  Github does support HTTPS.  You're saying that Github says Read/Write is supported over HTTPS but somehow it doesn't actually support it?  I don't think that's the case here.  Rather, instead of finding out what was wrong with the HTTPS connection, we will just use SSH and ignore the problem.

Comment: i have to do this every time i create a new repository. why? how can i change it permanently?

Comment: For those looking for a non ssh solution, check a few of the other answers here. Adding your username to the https url seems to work. (change config url so that https://@github.com/...  is https://UNAME@github.com/...)

Comment: I have created many repos before, and I'm positive that I was logged in to the github website when I created this one, nevertheless I had this issue happen (for the first time). BTW, I am using the SourceTree GUI, so I edited the remote's URL in the repo's settings panel.

Comment: I'm trying to edit '.git/config' on the repo 'Chronicle.git'  by putting in 'pico config' which returns:

    'repositoryformatversion = 0

    filemode = true

    bare = true'

I don't see a field titled 'url'. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: If you are using Phabricator and encountered the 403 error, it might be because you didn't set the VCS  (version control password) - which you provide when trying to access the remote repo

Comment: No, this doesn't solve the problem for me. I've changed config as described, but push gives me The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.129)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.129' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: you will also need to add ssh public key to your github account do the following :   1.Generate a new SSH key  With the command line still open, copy and paste the text below. Make sure you substitute in your GitHub email address.  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`  2.Add your key to the ssh-agent  configure the ssh-agent program to use your SSH key:  `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`  3.Add your SSH key to your account  -In your favorite text editor, open the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub file.  -Click Add SSH key in your github setting account

Comment: in my case the URL is of this format `url = https://github.com/viveksinghggits/bethere.git`. I think I logged into GIT with another user earlier some time. This is the exact error that I am getting: `remote: Permission to viveksinghggits/bethere.git denied to vivekstudent.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/viveksinghggits/bethere.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

Comment: In my case, I was trying to commit as I worked from home. I remembered to connect to my company's VPN, and voila. My mistake.

Comment: sorry.. can somebody help - where to find .git/config file?

Comment: Changing the URL worked for me without the 'ssh://' prefix. Thank you!

Comment: @rishijain bit late but maybe someone else will encounter the same issue: In my case I use SourceTree. In SourceTree go to: Repository --> Repository settings --> Edit Config File.

Else the file is located in the .git folder called: "config" (With no extension). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 523):

To definitely be able to login using `https` protocol, you should first set your *authentication credential* to the git **Remote URI**:

```
git remote set-url origin https://yourusername@github.com/user/repo.git
```

Then you'll be asked for a password when trying to `git push`.

In fact, this is on the http authentication format. You could set a password too:

```
https://youruser:password@github.com/user/repo.git
```

You should be aware that if you do this, your github password will be stored in plaintext in your .git directory, which is obviously undesirable.

Comment: SSH blocked at work so I have to use HTTPS. Adding the username fixes my issues.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No reason to manually edit a config file when there's a command line interface to it.

Comment: Also, for me, this way (https://username@github...) asked for password and worked, whereas ssh://git@github... failed expecting public key auth.

Comment: works and should be the accepted answer! Especially in environments in which ssh does not work, this is the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: Why exactly does this work, if you don't mind giving an explanation?

Comment: @Achint it's an authentication format. You could set your password too `https://youruser:password@github.com/user/repo.git` despite [not secure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5343146/667927)

Comment: Don't forget that in GitHub, you need to work on your forked project in order to participate to a project (and do a pull request to the master).

Comment: I tried using `https://username@github.com/user/repo.git` on my bosses server. I got this message `(gnome-ssh-askpass:21776): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:` I went and changed it to `https://username:passwrd@github.com ...` and now it works, but I was not happy having my password in the plain text file like that so I went and changed it back I wish there was a --password flag so you could use the first option if for some reason the system security wont let you get the password prompt.

Comment: @Ajay checkout this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506124/how-to-enter-command-with-password-for-git-pull

Comment: It's worth adding that you don't need to add your username to the URL for each repository, you can instead set it in global config: `git config --global credential.https://github.com.username YOUR_USERNAME`

Comment: I get `fatal: No such remote 'origin'`

Comment: Thanks Thiago, works like a charm... Should be the accepted answer for sure.

Comment: I agree that it should be the right answer, because  It is the solution for the https connection to the repo. In this context, where you are cloning the repo by https, talk about suggestion to change to ssh is like a workaround... and It is true that something (like where you are working behind a corporate proxy) connecting to a repo by ssh is not an option ... thanks +Thiago Fernandes, It help me

Comment: Just a note if you have this problem, if you have special characters in the username or password you need to URL encode them. For example, @ needs to be %40.

Comment: Worked for me with bit bucket, in fact did not need to run second command as it asks for password when pushing the change.

Comment: thanks, https://youruser:password@github.com/user/repo.git this solved my problem!!!

Comment: Good to note that the username needs to be URL-encoded. So if your username is your email, for example, you need to change `@` character from your username to `%40`. But this answer worked for me, thank you.

Comment: FYI, this trick keeps it from prompting me for my username (and password as well, if I put that in the url), but I still get the 403 that OP mentioned.

Comment: Password based authentication is now removed. https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/

Comment: This is what worked for me. This answer is correct.

Answer (score 133):

One small addition to [Sean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7771927/3472757).

Instead of editing `.git/config` file manually, you can use `git remote set-url` command.

In your case it should be:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/derekerdmann/lunch_call.git
```

I find it easier and cleaner, than messing around with dot-files.

- [help.github.com: Changing a remote's URL](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url)

Comment: I don't know if this is just an old post and git has changed, but as today to fix the problem I had to use `git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com:derekerdmann/lunch_call.git` with a colon between the github.com and the repo name

Answer (score 68):

Edit `.git/config` file under your repo directory

Find `url=` entry under section `[remote "origin"]`

Change it from `url=https://github.com/rootux/my-repo.git` to
`https://USERNAME@github.com/rootux/my-repo.git`

where `USERNAME` is your github user name

Comment: This answer did not apply to my problem. My url in `.git/config` is set to `https://github.com/myrepo/subproject'/.

Comment: Had this problem with Android Studio. Works fine.

Comment: My instinct is that this is more along the lines of being the right answer because other solutions either switch to SSH protocol or store password in plaintext.

Answer (score 52):

The other answers that suggest switching to SSH sort of miss the point. HTTPS is supported, but you must log in with you GITHUB password, not your SSH passphrase (which was what was giving me the same exact error).

I was having the same problem, but making sure to use my actual GitHub password at the terminal password prompt fixed the solution with no alteration to the config, or resorting to SSH.

The reason it is important to note this, is many public institutions (such as my school) will block SSH, but allow HTTPS (which is the only reason I started cloning over HTTPS in the first place).

Hope that helps anyone else having the same issue...

Comment: but why?  I didn't have to do that in the past.  Did a certificate expire, or something?

Comment: Not sure, I'm not an expert, that's just how I got it to work in my case :)

Comment: Same @Thufir. I have no idea why this suddenly worked.

Comment: I log on just fine with my username and password on the browser. BUT when i try to `git push` I am prompted for a u and p and the result is permission denied.... Do you know what I am missing?

Comment: As of recently (2021?) when prompted for the password, you must use a generated token (oauth), generated at the GitHub website under User Settings / Developer Settings / Personal access tokens.  And that generated token must include the "repo" scope.

Answer (score 46):

If you are using windows, sometimes this may happen because Windows stores credentials for outer repo (in our case github) in its own storage. And credentials that saved there can be different from those you need right now.

[image]

So to avoid this problem, just find github in this storage and delete saved credentials. After this, while pushing git will request your credentials and will allow you to push.

Comment: "You may have to check windows credential manager and delete the github entry under `control panel > user accounts > credential manager > Windows credentials > Generic credentials` " details from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37450495

Comment: exact answer (working for me perfectly)

Comment: Yes, it did the trick, other answers weren't working. After delete git:username under "Windows credentials > Generic credentials" then use the token for the password in CMD when asked after push command.

Answer (score 33):

Same error and resolution on **Mac OS X.**

Everything was working fine till I created a **new account on GitHub** and tried to push

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

And got the error:

*remote: Permission to NEWUSER/NEWREPO.git denied to OLDUSER. fatal: unable to access ‘https://github.com/NEWUSER/NEWREPO.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403*

It should have fixed by setting the user.name either for global or current repo

```
$ git config –-global user.name NEWUSER
$ git config user.name NEWUSER
```

But it didn’t.

**I got it fixed by deleting the OLDUSER associated with GitHub from Keychain Access app** under Passwords section. Then the push command went successful.

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

[reference](https://zeeawan.wordpress.com/2014/11/05/submit-your-project-to-github/)

Comment: Deleting the OLDUSER from the Keychain Access App worked for me

Comment: I got the same error, but for a different but related reason that required a different solution. I was trying to push to a repo where I don't have write access (I'm not a collaborator). This was more due to my lack of knowledge of how to contribute to a repo that isn't mine. I thought I could just create a new branch and then do a pull request. Not so. I have to fork the repo first, make my changes on the fork, then do a pull request from my forked repo to the original repo. Probably a dumb mistake on my part, but if I can make it, then I'm sure other n00bs could. :)

Answer (score 23):

This works for me -:

```
git remote set-url origin https://username@github.com/user/repo.git
```

Hope it helps

Comment: nice job. set user!

Comment: This solution helped with git v1.7 in CentOS 6.10 x86. I was expecting the password promopt to show up (instead of SSH key), and it did (by prepending `<username>@` before `github.com` in remote URL). Thank you!

Answer (score 20):

A lot of answers here, but this is what solved my problem.

**Since July 2020** you must use [Token authentication to access GitHub](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/) if you are using HTTPS.

So you must [generate an access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) in your profile settings page and use it as your password. Check the boxes necessary to write to the repository.

Now add your username to the repo with this command:

```
git remote set-url origin https://yourusername@github.com/user/repo.git
```

When you try to push, it will ask for your password. **Enter your newly generated token.**

If you are still having trouble pushing, use the web interface to fork it as a personal repo to isolate any permission problem. You'll be able to focus on solving the auth problem.

Answer (score 19):

I think @deepwaters got the answer correct for older versions. The HTTPS URL needs to have the username. I had git 1.7.0.4 and `git push origin master` wouldn't even ask for a password till I added it.

Answer (score 16):

Upgrade your git. GitHub has answered this question at https://help.github.com/articles/error-the-requested-url-returned-error-403.

Comment: It's half the answer, for sure. Other half is what we have here.

Answer (score 15):

A 403 code is "Forbidden".  The server saw your request and refused it.  Do you have permission to push to that repository?

Comment: Me and a friend are having the same problem. The repo is mine, and he can't push. How do we fix this?

Comment: how to get persmisson

Comment: add  your friend into the access list of repo.  https://help.github.jp/enterprise/2.11/user/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/

Answer (score 12):

Figured it out. I cloned over HTTPS. Setting up my public SSH keys, cloning over SSH, and pushing over SSH fixed it.

Comment: Hmmm... but what when you can't use anything but https, because of a corp firewall, for instance?... According to the github blog, the https access was added to github just for that purpose?

Comment: I really don't know. I always clone over SSH now.

Comment: Just for posterity (I noticed the timestamp), in regards to filofel's comment: Check out my answer listed above. I have the same restriction you mention, at my school, and found I was supplying the wrong password/passphrase to the terminal prompt. Hope it helps any others with the same issue.

Answer (score 11):

Do this for a temporary fix

`git push -u https://username:password@github.com/username/repo_name.git master`

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same error and the cause was stupid - I did not have privileges to commit to selected repository. I did not know that I have to

1. fork selected project first
2. clone repository locally
3. commit my changes locally
4. push changes to my github clone
5. request pull request to upstream

as described in https://help.github.com/categories/63/articles

Comment: Not stupid, this is the correct answer for most first-time contributors to public repositories.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was a first-time contributor to a public repository. This was my issue

Answer (score 10):

I actually had a very simple fix to this. All i did was edit the git config file differently after cloning the repository.  The remote origin url is what you need to edit in your default **config** file. It should look like seen below

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = https://*username*@github.com/*username*/*repository*.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: ^ this (or any one of its variants below)

Comment: Adding the username before github.com fixed it for me.

Comment: You are welcome @ÅdəəlÅhmåd . Support the effort by upvoting the answer so that many others can appreciate.

Answer (score 9):

1. Click on your repository
2. On the right hand side, click on "Settings"
3. On the left hand side option panel, click on "Collaborators"
4. Add the person name you know in GitHub
5. Click "Add Collaborators"

After this our "Push to Git" worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

change it from

```
url=https://MichaelDrogalis@github.com/derekerdmann/lunch_call.git
```

to

```
url=ssh://git@github.com/derekerdmann/lunch_call.git
```

It works!

Do not forget the "git" before the "@".

Comment: It worked for me (using CentOS Server with RStudio behind proxy).
Set proxy first : `git config --global http.proxy http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxy.server.com:port`
Then use the command `git remote set-url origin` to switch the adress.

Answer (score 7):

Just add you username into url like this :
https://islam9@github.com/islam9/bootstrap-rtl

please check:
http://islamkhalil.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/github-error-pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal/

Answer (score 7):

**Below is the solution**

**For Windows you can find the keys here:**

control panel > user accounts > credential manager > Windows credentials > Generic credentials

Next, remove the Github keys.

**In mac**

1-In Finder, search for the Keychain Access app.

2In Keychain Access, search for github.com.

3-Find the "internet password" entry for github.com.

4-Edit or delete the entry accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

For those having permission denied *403* error while using **ssh**(according to [Xiao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7771927/4994239)) or **http** urls
try these commands

```
>git config --global --unset-all credential.helper

>git config --unset-all credential.helper
```

with administrator rights

```
>git config --system --unset-all credential.helper
```

Comment: Now every time Git will ask for login and password. Save them through `git config --global credential.helper store`.

Answer (score 5):

None of the above answers worked for my `enterprise` GitHub account. Follow these steps for pushing via ssh key generation way.

Create a repo by visiting your git account.

Generate ssh key:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Copy the contents of the file ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to your SSH keys in your GitHub account settings.
Test SSH key:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
clone the repo:
git clone git://github.com/username/your-repository
```

Now cd to your git clone folder and do:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/your-repository.git
```

Now try editing a file (try the README) and then do:

```
git add -A
git commit -am "my update msg"
git push -u origin master
```

Update: new git version seems to recommend not to have any file while new repo is created. Hence make aa blank repo.

Comment: This answer helped me, but you must be sure that your keys have default names like `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`, otherwise, you will continue to get the error `Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`. So either rename your key to the default name or use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11251797/1335142) to clarify how to set a custom path to ssh key.

Answer (score 5):

if you get 403 error with github,

sure to check all checkboxs when create token:

https://github.com/settings/tokens

i think github token generate page has design flaw.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me:

My repo was a *fork* and still linked to the the parents repo.

```
git remote -v
```

Will tell you if it is your repo or not.

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git
```

Allows you to reconfigure it to your repo and then allow you to push.

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar issue and most of the answer did not work in my case, i was getting permission denied 403 forbidden error. Following steps helped me to resolve the issue:

Install git CLI by below command if you have brew installed:

```
brew install gh
```

Reference to install git CLI https://github.com/cli/cli#installation

then run

```
gh auth login
```

it will ask you following questions, answer like this,

```
What account do you want to log into? GitHub.com
? What is your preferred protocol for Git operations? HTTPS
? Authenticate Git with your GitHub credentials? Yes
? How would you like to authenticate GitHub CLI? Login with a web browser
```

It will generate code for you, enter generated to code your browser for authentication.

```
! First copy your one-time code: 14*B-E2*7

Press Enter to open github.com in your browser... 
✓ Authentication complete.
```

By following above steps you will be able to `push` code to your repository.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone curious, my mac machine vs lucid vm ran git 1.7.6 vs 1.7.0.4, and the exact same repo was pushable from my mac (newer git) but not the VM

Same curl version. Perhaps some older git versions don't support https pushes?

Comment: Yes, https push to github works here (even through proxy with password).  I use git 1.7.3. For me, it failed first because I typed the wrong password.

Comment: It works for me with git 1.7.1, but there is one thing you have to pay attention too (and that was what I missed in my first try): Give the user name in the HTTPS-URL, i.e. `url=https://username@github.com/username/repo.git`

Answer (score 3):

Add the user name as part of the URL and This error happens because the git command is hitting http instead of https. So set the url

```
git remote set-url origin https://<username>@github.com/Path_to_repo.git
```

After which you will be prompted for password:

Answer (score 3):

Try below command using administrator permission. This command solved my issue. Hope it will resolve your problem.

```
git config --system --unset-all credential.helper
```

Comment: This command reset all user credentials. And let user to give user id and token again. For my case issue resolve by doing this. I was logged in another git account.

Answer (score 3):

If SSH is not allowed for some reason, **HTTPS is also ok**.

To push the commits by **HTTPS**, you should use the [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) and make sure the **read and write** is available in `Scopes` which define the access for personal tokens.

Setting in GitHub as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured out my own variation of this problem.

The issue was not changing the protocol from https to ssl, but instead,
setting the Github global username and email! (I was trying to push to a 
private repository.

```
git config --global user.email "your_github_email_@email.com"

git config --global user.name "Your full name"
```

Comment: Does not work for me. Config has been set, use https://github.com/.. with no '@' in it

Answer (score 2):

Github has page dedicated to troubleshooting this error:

https://help.github.com/articles/https-cloning-errors

In my case it turned out that using a new version of git (1.8.5.2) solved this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who didn't solve their problem with these solutions follow this thread:

"This happens when two git accounts are being used on same machine"
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52046047/7861886

it has **Windows** solution and also i have added **Mac** solution for Mac users in comments.

Answer (score 2):

For windows Go to **"Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager"** and remove the entry shown in the figure and push with username/password.

[image: Credential Manager]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem right now, and it turned out that my server /etc/resolver.conf file had a bad ip address.  Might help others.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because my coworker accidentially disabled the repository that this repository was forked from. Just might check to ensure that the original git(hub) repo actually still exists.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an accounting issue. The Github account of the upstream (private) repo owner may not be financial. I've seen this where the client's credit card expired.

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me is changing from http to ssh:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repoName.git
```

then check it with `git remote -v`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My case was: I'd initialized git repo locally before I created it on github, then I tried to add remote branch. I solved my issue by changing the order of actions: created a repo on github site, then inited it locally. But it's not the case fr them who like to do all from command line as me.

Answer (score 1):

After changing https to **http** within gitbox app, it worked for me.

Comment: got 403 while accessing by http.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there is nothing wrong with settings, and there are some problems on github servers.

https://status.github.com - current status of github :)

Comment: You can also get GitHub status updates [from their Twitter status account](https://twitter.com/githubstatus).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was getting the above error for my **email id with github was not verified yet**.
GitHub was giving this warning of un-verified email.

Verifying the email, and then pushing worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Cloning with `ssh` instead of `https` solved this issue for me

[image: ssh cloning]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error was caused because I have no permissions in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same kind of error. Unable to access 403.
In My Case, None of these answers worked. So i tried the below, It worked.

1. Remove user.email and user.password from git config
2. Remove the saved credentials from Keychain.
3. Restart the system.
4. Now push the code, will ask you the user/pass
5. Proceed by giving user/pass.

Code pushed successfully

!macOS!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that helped me is this answer for another question:

[Git's famous "ERROR: Permission to .git denied to user"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335197/gits-famous-error-permission-to-git-denied-to-user#answer-40907049)

In summary, if you are like me with Windows, search "Credential manager" and open it. There, you can find your Git credential. Change the username (which you must have changed to something else).

You can also find it under "Control Panel" - "User Account" - "Credential Manager".

Answer (score 1):

Make git repository from private to public.

Comment: i don't recommend doing that at all, keep it private, use access token and give permissions for that token !
you will find it here :
https://github.com/settings/tokens

Answer (score 1):

I had solved this issue of Permission denied by just:

1.) upgrading the git to latest version.

2.) Changing remote url to the format "https://username@github.com/username/repo_name.git" through command entered in git-bash "git remote set-url origin https://username@github.com/username/repo_name.git"

Previously, I was using the version 2.28 so I was not getting the Login Screen Prompt. Also by changing the url I was able to login with git-hub credentials and push the changes to the repo

Comment: Indeed, the outdated Git cli on the old machine was the reason, trying the same commands from the recent version on my new laptop solved it.

Answer (score 1):

The support for password authentication while accessing Github from CLI(Command Line Interface) has been removed on August 13, 2021 by replacing them with personal access token.

[Steps to create personal acess token](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

**By default tokens always include read-only access** to all public repositories on GitHub. Hence, to give push or pull and rights you need to select the appropriate "Scope" while generating the access token.

The scope for public repositories is public_repo, and for private repositories is repo. A token with one of those scopes is the most limited access possible for Git push or pull access.

Now, when you are prompted for your username and password, provide your GitHub username and the access token in place of the password.

For the description of other available scopes refer the [Github Documention](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add one more scenario that happened to me, my company requires SSO hence when I created/renewed my new publishing token I forgot to authorize it and started to get these 403 responses from github:

[image]

[image]

I suspect this distraction might be common

Answer (score 0):

One another possible reason is, you might have exceeded their plan limit.

To fix this issue and restore write access to the repo, either your account plan will need to be upgraded, or some of your collaborators will need to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BitBucket your account can be put into read only mode for the following reasons:

> - We are upgrading our storage segments and cannot accept new data.
> - We are rolling out changes that require no new writes.
> - The owner of the repository needs to upgrade their account to accept    a higher number of users.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Repositories+in+Read-Only+Mode

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with bitbucket but I waited 5 min and then I retried and it was working well. Sometimes it could be a problem with the provider.

Comment: Hmm, just like what [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22798784/456814) says about GitHub servers, yeah?

Comment: You can get Bitbucket status updates from [their status page](http://status.bitbucket.org/) and maybe also [their Twitter account](https://twitter.com/bitbucket).

Answer (score 0):

Edit .git/config file under your repo directory

Find url= entry under section [remote "origin"]

Change it from url=https://github.com/rootux/ms-Dropdown.git to https://USERNAME@github.com/rootux/ms-Dropdown.git

where USERNAME is your github user name

=> This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On more reason could be e-mail verification on github.com

Just log in to github.com and check if there is no message for you, to confirm your e-mail address. Confirm, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve such 403 during push error you have to go in .git directory config file and change the given line:

```
precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
http://git@github.com:abc/xyz.git
```

Change the line to this

```
precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
ssh://git@github.com/abc/xyz.git
```

This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

**If none of the solutions worked for you, quickly read this answer [might be your case]:**

For those of you like me who went through all of these [great] answers but still have trouble pushing your commits, there is potentially one other reason for failure of a push.

Check your git repository (wherever it is, GitHub, BitBucket, ...) to see if everything is OK. In my case, after spending a lot of time figuring out what my problem is (even blaming PyCharm's new edition! :) ) I realized that I did some stupid things and my BitBucket repo exceeded the 2GB limit and automatically turned to a read-only repo and that was why I could not push any new commit. And, that exactly causes you getting the same error (403: unable to access the URL.)

Answer (score 0):

I was signed in as a different github user previously(say user1) . For my actual github account(say user2) I was able to clone a newly created repo in github but I was not able to push the changes.

I tried all the answers mentioned above including removing credential from Windows Credential manager but nothing worked.

In the end what worked was launching github Windows App. Navigate to Settings->Options and voila the logged in user was user1. Click Logout from that user and login as required user in this case user2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with this same error telling me this

> remote: Permission to user/repo.git denied to user2.

The problem with this is that on Windows and Mac, it's stored in cache a key path to Github.

To fix this on Mac just do this

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
```

Nothing will prompt at the console.

Then just do a normal push and it should let you write your username and password again from Github.

```
git commit -m "First Commit"
```

For window uses see answers above ^ with stored credentials

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your origin using SSH key instead of HTTP.

If you can initiate using SSH key then URL starts with:

```
git@github.com:<YOUR REPO URL>
```

Now you can add, commit & Push to your corresponding Branch

Answer (score 0):

Provide write access for the user.

After providing the access.Pull the code once and then push it.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have enough permissions to push to the repository if you do
then try running these commands

```
git config --global user.email youremail@domain.
git config --global user.name username
git config --global user.password yourpassword
```

hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I had proxy I couldn't access to my repository

```
C:\Users\YourUser\.gitconfig
```

remove bullshit proxy and it should work

[image]

then try again to clone by gitbash

```
 git clone http://********************
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether someone has mentioned this before or not.

I was having this problem with Bitbucket, and I noticed one thing. If you have this, for example,

```
git push https://myrepo:myRepoPassword@bitbucket.org/myrepo/myrepo.git --all
```

Notice the @ in there, right after the password. See, if your password ends with a @, you'd have two @@ instead of one. In my case, it was the password that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me because **the repository was disabled** (a repository can be disabled by the owner or Github may disable all private repositories of an account if the account does not pay it's bill).

So you should contact the repository owner and inform him that the repository is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If All else fails. Just make sure you didn't Archive your project. That was my problem, puts the whole solution in a read only mode.

Answer (score 0):

This 403 Error (Access denied) can occur when you haven't accepted the invite link in your email or github repo account.

After you click invitation link, you can add remote repo with following commands:

```
git remote add <name> <url>
git push —set-upstream <repo_name> master
```

Example:

```
git remote add ProgrammingFoundationExam https://github.com/itprowhoami/ProgrammingFoundationExam.git
git push --set-upstream ProgrammingFoundationExam master
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you are on the correct branch
   `git status`
2. Check your repository permissions (write permission is needed)

Answer (score 0):

I am having same issue. None of the above works for me. The problem is Github has block my write permission. I have changed my password. Now I am able to push.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Mac and got the error fatal: unable to access The requested URL returned error: 403.

I did change my GitHub account details.

I had to edit my keychain entry for GitHub and update the username to the new username.  You can easily find KeyChain in the top search of the MAC.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and noticed that the repository I was trying to push my branch was `private`. So, try the following procedure:

1. Make sure you have access to that private repository
2. `Fork` the repository first. You will notice that the `repository URL` will contain your GitHub `username`
3. Clone it now like this --> `git clone https://github.com/your-github-username/example-repository.git`
4. Enter in the cloned repository folder --> `cd repository-directory`

**Do whatever you want to do with your cloned repository. Staying in the same cloned repository directory move to the next steps**

5. Check all the branches. This will list up the available branches --> `git branch`
6. Create your branch now --> `git checkout -b your-branch-name`
7. Run `git branch` to check if your branch is created
8. Now run this command --> `git add .`
9. Commit your changes --> `git commit -m "your message"`
10. Push your branch --> `git push origin your-branch-name`
11. Check GitHub site to make sure your branch is pushed now

That's All

Answer (score 0):

This error happened when we clone someone repository from github.
this might easily be solve by updating  origin by using

**git remote set-url origin 'Your repository origin'**

then after this apply

**git push -f origin master**

This might be very helpful for all

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar error

> fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/xxxx/yyyy.git/': The
> requested URL returned error: 403

I resolved by switching network, ( by changing IP). initially, I faced an issue in my system, then I tried with new network (by using a mobile hotspot) and did a git pull,

again I moved back to the primary network, and i was able to perform all git operations with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

If no other methods worked, try this:

- **McOS** only

1. Go to `Finder`, search for the `Keychain Access`.
2. While in `Keychain Access`, search for `github.com`.
3. Then look for `internet password` double click that.
4. Once double clicked, look for `show password` then enter your computer password to access it.
5. You should now be able to `edit` or `delete` the current token. After you've edited the token or deleted it save your changes and you should be able to push your code.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue **The requested URL returned error: 403** in android studio.

I have followed the below steps:-

1. Right-click in project name --->  git ----> add
2. After that open one dialog ----> Enter generate the by GitHub.
3. Then Write the Commit message ----> And Select the Push option.

**Note:- So you must generate an access token in your profile settings page and use it as your password.**

Answer (score -3):

What worked for me was to reset the BitBucket password on the portal and then trying to push again.