# Error Pushing my Repository to Github

Tags: git, github, terminal

I typed into the terminal:

```
Parkers-MacBook-Pro:first_app ppreyer$ git push -u origin master
Username: 
Password:
```

And I get this error:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/ppreyer/first_app.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with my username and password but I feel like I'm entering in the right information. Is there a way to figure out what my username and password are?

Comment: try [your password](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8898992/262852)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your remote url is wrong.

Try running the following commands:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git
git push origin master
```

Comment: After I type git push origin master I get this error:error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git'    Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might have cloned the public read only url. 
Also Its better if you can setup ssh key and add it in your github account .

Follow this [guide](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) .

To fix the problem you can facing , You can follow the answer posted by Gazier. I am adding one more way of doing it.

1. edit `.git/config` file under your repo directory
2. find `url=entry` under section `[remote "origin"]`
3. make sure it is `git@github.com:ppreyer/first_app.git`

Now try to push the origin to master

Answer (score 0):

Add Your GitHub Username to Your "remote.origin.url" just before github.com in your url:

https://ppreyer@github.com/ppreyer/first_app.git