# Cannot push to git repository - permission denied

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I have a following problem:

```
$ git push -u origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have already checked the connection doing this:

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
```

and output looks good, I was correctly authenticated.

While checking further, I noticed that:

```
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

I have tried to run ssh-agent, but nothing changed:

```
$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-A1mhFqvqncuO/agent.766; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=767; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 767;
$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

I am using Arch Linux. Any help would be strong appreciated! Thanks in advance!

[Github diagnostic help here.](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/)

Comment: show your `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: My solution has been to regenerate my public key. Seems to work for me under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I had the similar problem and my problem was solved by running the following command to add my key to the list of known keys:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Hope it solves yours too. ;)

Comment: This has helped me so many times. Is there a way to just permanently add this so i don't always have to go through the motions.

Answer (score 6):

If you haven't already read it, you should look through the GitHub help page for this error:

*[Error: Permission denied (publickey)](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey)*

Every time that I've had this problem, it was due to the last issue listed on that page: I didn't have the public key from my current workstation attached to my GitHub account. Of course, GitHub also provides instructions on [how to attach your public key to your account](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#step-4-add-your-ssh-key-to-your-account).

---

**tl;dr**

Make sure your current public key is attached to your GitHub account.

Comment: Yes, I've read this and my public key is attached to my github account.

Comment: Dang. If the public key for the current user on your current machine matches the one registered in github then I'm not going to be of any help—that's been my problem every time I've run into this error.

Answer (score 6):

You need to do in your console (*if you use an a putty ssh client*):

1. Generate the keys, if keys not exist:

   ```
   cd ~/.ssh && ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ```

Don't forget password, entered at this step!

1. Output your public key to screen:

   ```
   cd ~/.ssh && cat id_rsa.pub
   ```
2. Copy this string by click and move a mouse pointer from begin output to end. No need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> or any more keys.
3. Log in your account on GitHub and add this public key to https://github.com/settings/ssh
4. Now you can use your git locally.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this will solve your problem since you tested `ssh -vT git@github.com` directly and it worked, but you are using the `ssh-agent` improperly. You need to run

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
Agent pid 767
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

This will evaluate the environment export commands and allow your `ssh-add` and `ssh` commands to communicate with the agent. Alternatively, you can ask the agent to start a shell, terminal, etc. and it will set up the proper environment:

```
$ ssh-agent bash
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

In this case, the shell is running as a child of the `ssh-agent` and the agent will shut down when the shell quits.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue on my Ubuntu and then I realize that I am on `sudo` mode, once I just access `remote` without `sudo` it went well.

That's how I get rid if the issue, hope it may help.

Answer (score 2):

Permission denied (public key). I encountered this problem today, but I found a solution finally, and successfully solved my problem.

Maybe you should verify following issues：

1. you have a github account
2. git config your username and -mail
3. generate a ssh-key pri/pub pair and add the public key to your git account, please check this may give you help: [generating new ssh key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key/) and [cannot push git repository 'permission denied'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674647/cannot-push-to-git-repository-permission-denied)
4. check that ssh-key is successfully added: `ssh -V username@github.com`
5. good luck!

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had this problem with GitLab because I was working with non-default SSH key pair paths.
@NEO 's answer works perfectly:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/other_id_rsa
```

However, I had to do this everytime that I opened a new terminal.

To make this change permanent, you have to edit `~/.ssh/config` and add the following:

```
Host gitlab.company.com
RSAAuthentication yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/config/private-key-filename
```

For more detailed info check [gitlab's documentation](https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README#working-with-non-default-ssh-key-pair-paths).

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this out from ([Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)):

To definitely be able to login using https protocol, you should first set your authentication credential to the git Remote URI:

```
git remote set-url origin https://yourusername@github.com/user/repo.git
```

Then you'll be asked for a password when trying to git push.

Answer (score -1):

fatal: unable to access
'https://......': The requested
URL returned error: 403
if you when push your code and see this Error
you follow this address in windows

**⇒ Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager**
and remove past account in GitHub

Comment: The poster has specified that he had this problem under Arch Linux