# Windows - TortoiseGit: Host does not exist fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

My laptop blew up, so I am trying to setup a new one without success.  When I try and use TortoiseGit to clone a GitHub repo, I get:

```
Host does not exist fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

git.exe clone      --progress -v  "git@github.com:me/mystuff.git"    "C:\git\stuff"

Cloning into 'C:\git\stuff'...
Unable to open connection:
Host does not exist fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

This is a common problem, but I could only find solutions for Unix, not Windows.

The way I set it up is as follows:

1. downloaded and installed tortoise git, selecting the default option to use putty (plink?) instead of openssh (which I don't have).
2. downloaded and installed git
3. putty and puttygen were already installed on the machine.
4. used puttygen to create a key.  saved it as something.ppk, and cut and pasted the public it into a new key here: https://github.com/settings/ssh
5. right clicked on a dir and tried to cone a repo using URL like: "git@github.com:me/mystfuff.git" and a type of "WEB".  The URL I copied from GitHub's "ssh clone URL".

Any ideas?

I don't want to use the proprietary GitHub client, as I want it to be usable with TortoiseGit, Git Bash and even Eclipse (although I have never got Eclipse to work with GitHub).

Comment: "*This is a common problem, but I could only find solutions for Unix, not windows.*" What are the Unix solutions that you found?

Comment: @cupcake, this for example: "ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674647/cannot-push-to-git-repository-permission-denied

Comment: I was having the same problem. The firewall I'm using was blocking the "TortoiseGitPlink.exe" process. I added an exception and it worked. Check if yours is a similar issue