# cant add a file into github

Tags: github

I want to add a file into github as follow:

```
git init
touch test.txt
git add test.tst
git cmmit -m'testtest'
git push origin master
```

then it will raise this exception:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/yacheng1127/YWProject.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

then I verify the public key is attached to my github account:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi yacheng1127! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

$ ssh-add -l
2048 1a:a1:33:26:21:68:7e:9c:26:19:fb:74:a4:d1:6b:bd yacheng1127@gmail.com (RSA)
```

then I check my remote url:

```
$ git remote -vorigin   
origin      https://github.com/yacheng1127/YWProject.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/yacheng1127/YWProject.git (push)
```

I don't know where is the problem. could somebody help me? thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)

Comment: I see "git cmmit" versus "git commit" ?

Comment: I'm so so so sorry.I inputted into wrong passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ssh key is used when you use the "git://" url for your remote, you can change this (https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url).

But "https://" should work too (read/write), but it can't use your ssh key nor ssh agent, you should give git your github login and password :

https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#password-caching

Comment: I do Password caching but it still doesn't work.@julien-palard