# git produces Gtk-WARNING: cannot open display

Tags: git, version-control, github, ssh

I've been working on my project remotely through the command line on a machine to which I don't have admin rights and after running `git push origin master` I get the following error message:

```
(gnome-ssh-askpass:29241): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

My `.git/config` file has the following contents:

> ```
>     [core]
>        repositoryformatversion = 0
>        filemode = true
>        bare = false
>        logallrefupdates = true 
>     [remote "origin"]
>        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>        url = https://username@github.com/username/repository.git 
>     [branch "master"]
>        remote = origin
>        merge = refs/heads/master
> ```

I was getting the 403 error earlier. Following the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed/9575906#9575906), I put my username before the @ sign in the remote url and since then, I've been getting the Gtk error.

When I login to the machine using `ssh -X` and try to push, I get the following error:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
(gnome-ssh-askpass:31922): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:localhost:10.0
```

If I change the url of the remote to `git@github.com:username/repository.git`, then the error is:

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I guess you are using ssh. Use ssh -X instead.  This means a password dialog is trying to open up, but couldn't because there is no X.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using ssh explicitly, just calling `git push origin master`, so I don't know how to apply what you're saying?

Comment: May I know from where you are pushing to the server? I mean from which machine? How have you logged into that machine?

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I didn't fully read your question. Your "url" should either be
`git@github.com:username/repo.git` or
`https://github.com/username/repo.git`
But you are using a mix of both.

Comment: Oh sorry, I get what you mean now. I tried logging into the machine using `ssh -X`, but that didn't help either. See the updated question above.

Comment: Quite strange. Are you behind a firewall? Are you able to ping `github.com`

Comment: Strange indeed. I'm behind a proxy, but both http_proxy and https_proxy are set in .bashrc. It seems I can't ping github.com, but I can clone repositories, that works OK (and it only started working after setting those environment variables a while ago).

Comment: My take on this is that you're dealing with the GNOME keyring.  I mean, when you attempt to connect to your server, SSH notices there's an active desktop session and tries to spawn a GNOME keyring credentials helper to ask you for a password for your key, and fails because it's unable to connect to your display.

The exact cause it unknown. Could you elaborate on your setup? What machine runs a GNOME session -- your local one of the remote?

Comment: @JohnManak: If you are behind a proxy, mostly your ping requests won't get any responses. But you can clone. :)

Answer (score 348, accepted):

I have finally discovered a solution to the problem. As it was described [here](http://kartzontech.blogspot.it/2011/04/how-to-disable-gnome-ssh-askpass.html), I ran the following command in the terminal:

```
  unset SSH_ASKPASS
```

and then running `git push origin master` works the way it should. You can also add the line to your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Just wanted to add that it was this script setting this variable on my CentOS 6.7 system:  /etc/profile.d/gnome-ssh-askpass.sh

Comment: Now I'm getting a `error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 417`

Comment: I did this and when I try to connect to SSH now I'm just left with a blank shell where I can type and doesn't do anything instead of a prompt for my password. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19):

I recently dealt with this behavior on a RedHat 5 machine where our Git version was 1.7.4.1.

I didn't have a high degree of confidence that `unset SSH_ASKPASS` wouldn't have unintended consequences, so I wanted to see if there was another solution.

I couldn't tell for certain, but it seems that a [patch for this problem was in the works](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-calls-SSH-ASKPASS-even-if-DISPLAY-is-not-set-td5825303.html) around the same time that our version of Git had been published.  So, it seemed to me that it was reasonable to hope that a more recent version would correct the behavior.

And indeed it did. **Upgrading to the 1.8 branch of Git resolved the problem.**  The error message is still displayed for some odd reason, but you are correctly prompted for your password and allowed to continue.

Comment: The problem in RHEL 5 (CentOS 5 etc.) is in file /etc/profile.d/gnome-ssh-askpass.sh (owned by openssh-askpass package) where SSH_ASKPASS environment variable is blindy set to /usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass and this does not work if there is no X (ie. logged in via PuTTY over SSH). You may simply comment out the line in this file (do not delete file or it will be recovered after update of openssh-askpass package). Or remove package openssh-askpass completely (yum remove openssh-askpass).

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked for me (ssh'ing via Cygwin on Windows 10 into a RHEL 6.8 server and trying to clone a github.com repo from the RHEL box) so what I did was clone via an SSH key rather than HTTPS username/password. e.g. I used git@github.com:MyUsername/myproject.git rather than the https url. I also appropriately uploaded my public key into Github. This method worked fine.

Note: Of the above solutions, I actually didn't try upgrading to the 1.8 branch of git

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to login using ssh -Y to the remote server so the dialogue box can appear graphically.

Like the OP, logging in via ssh -X didn't work. When trying to push, the server simply repeated the same error message - `(gnome-ssh-askpass:29241): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:` - as it did when logging via ssh with no X11 forwarding. This is slightly different behavior from what the OP reported when he tried ssh -X as his error message changed slightly from just using ssh.

However, for me, once logged in using ssh -Y: there was no error, the password dialogue box popped up, I typed the password in, and GitHub accepted the push.

As a forewarning, ssh -Y can open up security problems as you are treating the remote server as a trusted client (https://askubuntu.com/questions/35512/what-is-the-difference-between-ssh-y-trusted-x11-forwarding-and-ssh-x-u). So be careful when using it.