# using the git client on a headless linux server

Tags: linux, git

How do I force the git-client to use the console/terminal only.
When I ssh into my remote/headless linux computer and try to run:

git clone https://myname@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git

git complains and gives me this error:
  (gnome-ssh-askpass:2769): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

I dont want to use a graphical interface nor ssh -X.
I just want to configure the git-client to use the terminal only.

Im using CentOs and got the git-client with yum install git.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["git push" produces Gtk-WARNING](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077971/git-push-produces-gtk-warning)

Answer (score 26):

You can disable `gnome-ssh-askpass` in the current session by unsetting the `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable:

```
unset SSH_ASKPASS
```

You could probably add it in your `.bashrc` or `.profile` with a conditional check whether the user logged in using SSH. Something like:

```
[ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ] && unset SSH_ASKPASS
```

BTW, [someone else](http://www.kerneltrap.com/mailarchive/git/2010/12/11/46807) has also complained about the git's behavior of invoking the SSH_ASKPASS program blindly without determining if it is a GUI session or not. If you read the full thread, it would explain it is not possible to use `DISPLAY` environment variable to detect this. Also there is no mention of whether that patch was accepted or not.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more on [ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]?? what does the square bracket means??  My bash shell seems not to accept those.

Comment: @WeishiZeng - The square brackets indicate a test expression. The command checks that if the current shell is running within a SSH session, and if so, unsets the SSH_ASKPASS environment variable. More info about test expressions here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/test

Answer (score 5):

Based on Tobu's answer, I ended up with this in my `~/.bashrc` - I guess you'll want it in `~/.bash_profile` if you are using git from an ssh session:

```
export GIT_ASKPASS=
```

which seems to prevent the annoying gnome-ssh-askpass dialogue, using the CLI password prompt.

Unsetting `SSH_ASKPASS`, which is the advice that seems most common, presumably *could* have some unintended side effects.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your ssh-askpass command to something that is not using a UI (atm it is `gnome-ssh-askpass` as seen from the error message).

Answer (score 2):

Exporting

```
GIT_ASKPASS=true
```

will disable any prompting.

Starting with Git 2.3, you can use

```
GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0
```

or write a short script that does `echo quit=1` and use it for `core.askpass`.

Comment: I use HTTPS not SSH. After much research "export GIT_ASKPASS=true" before a "git pull" is the only thing that worked for me. Upgrading to GIT 1.8 might work as well but this was not an option for me.