# Git clone error "(gnome-ssh-askpass:11720): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:"

Tags: bitbucket

I got this error when I tried to clone a repo in bit bucket.

> "(gnome-ssh-askpass:11720): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:"

The command used is:

```
git clone https://user@bitbucket.org/repo.git scripts/
```

Comment: Solved:unset SSH_ASKPASS

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["git push" produces Gtk-WARNING](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077971/git-push-produces-gtk-warning)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Run below command and then try again:

```
unset SSH_ASKPASS
```