# Failed to push changes to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I try to push my changes to GitHub for two days, I read tens of discussions, but it still does not work. I think that I do something fundamentally wrong, I cannot explain it otherwise. I feel really angry after ten lost hours for activity that would take 30 seconds with SubVersion.

Originally I started from Intellij Idea cloning this URL: https://github.com/hhru/subscribe.git. But push did not work, access denied. I tried [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed), changed repo to svn, created SSH keys, updated windows environment with plink and home. I was able to test ssh connection but push still did not work. I break it so badly after another tries that I could not even pull changes.

Then I uninstalled git and installed github for windows, located my repository and it displayed one commit to synchronize. It failed again and tell me to run git cmd. Ok, I googled again and ran `git status` - one commit in front of repository. But `git push` failed again with 403 error.

Then I removed the repository from GitHub for windows and clicked *Clone id desktop* button in GitHub web. I have fresh clone with no changes - nothing to sync. I opened git command line in new project and ran `git push` again:

```
C:\dev\GitHub\subscribe [master]> git push
remote: Permission to hhru/subscribe.git denied to ba6a24dc485381dfe92d13800d0315c132787d30.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/hhru/subscribe.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
C:\dev\GitHub\subscribe [master]> git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I really do not understand it. I thought that GitHub is open and I do not need to ask for permission to submit pull request. But it seems that I do not have privileges. Or what else could be wrong? I feel really desperate :-(

Comment: Attempting to push to somebody else's repo != a pull request.  Try this: https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests.

Comment: Why did somebody downvote? Hint for downvoting: "This question does show any effort, it is unclear or not useful".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the trouble you're having is that you think you can push directly to `hhru/subscribe` without having commit access to that repository. While anyone can clone or fork your code from GitHub, only people you give commit access to a repository can change it directly in your repository.

In order to make a pull request, you need to first fork the repository, push your changes to your own repository, and then create a pull request from the GitHub website.

How this is done is explained in the [Fork A Repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) and [Using Pull Requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests) sections of the GitHub documentation.

#### Further reading:

- [Collaborating](https://help.github.com/categories/63/articles) in the GitHub documentation.

Comment: I see, it makes sense. I will try. So I was right that there is something FUNDAMENTALLY wrong with my attempts.

Comment: Finished, I shall have asked yesterday morning. But you know, people start downvoting that your question is duplicate ..

Comment: Surely you should be able to: clone to desktop > make changes > fork > then sync changes to your repository. The flow is broken here.

Comment: @zboarda: Not everyone uses GitHub for Windows. Personally I prefer not doing so.

Comment: @SebastianPaaskeTørholm Why not use it on windows?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue if you mistakenly click the clone this repository button on the repo rather than selecting to fork first.  In this case you are working on the code for the actual repo rather than your own fork.

Fork the repo to your own github account and clone that repo.  Then copy (or push) your changes to your own repo and you should be ok.