# fatal: HTTP request failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

I unload the application ROR on Heroku and I face a problem: fatal: HTTP request failed and other problem:  error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/priroda/first_app.git/info/refs

```
ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~$ mkdir rails_projects
ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~$ cd rails_projects
ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/rails_projects$ rails new first_app
ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/rails_projects$ cd first_app
ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/rails_projects/first_app$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/ark/rails_projects/first_app/.git/
ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/rails_projects/first_app$ git add .
ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/rails_projects/first_app$ git commit -m "Initialize repository"

ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/rails_projects/first_app$ git log
commit e8586bdf77a1aa260c25987c4860891333659033
Author: Ark <kotinoka2014@rambler.ru>
Date:   Fri Jun 20 19:21:19 2014 +0400

    Initialize repository

ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/rails_projects/first_app$ git remote add origin https://github.com/priroda/first_app.git

ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/rails_projects/first_app$ git push -u origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': priroda
Password for 'https://priroda@github.com': 
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/priroda/first_app.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have access rights to the repository. If so:

- Check the settings on your repo
- Try to push using a SSH URL for the remote (all about git remote URLs [here](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use)).

Another issue could be that the  repo already exists… if you'd try to push to an existing repository, that would fail to prevent data loss.