# How can I push to my fork from a clone of the original repo?

Tags: git, github

I created a fork (let's call it `myrepo`) of another repository (let's call it `orirepo`) on GitHub. Later, I cloned `orirepo`.

```
git clone https://github.com/original/orirepo.git
```

I modified about 20 files, then I staged my change and made a commit

```
git add
git commit
```

However, when I tried to push

```
git push
```

I got this error:

```
remote: Permission to original/orirepo.git denied to mylogin.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/original/orirepo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I know I made a mistake: I should have cloned my fork rather than `orirepo`, but it's too late for that now.
How could I push to my fork rather than to `origin/orirepo`, which I don't have write access to?

Comment: If only there's an IDE that does this automatically - VS Code

Comment: "Just switch your IDE bro" is unhelpful, @scoochy

Answer (score 291, accepted):

By default, when you clone a repository

- that resides at `https://github.com/original/orirepo.git`,
- whose current branch is called `master`,

then

- the local config of the resulting clone lists only one remote called `origin`, which is associated with the URL of the repository you cloned;
- the local `master` branch in your clone is set to *track* `origin/master`.

Therefore, if you don't modify the config of your clone, Git interprets

```
git push
```

as

```
git push origin master:origin/master
```

In other words, `git push` attempts to push your local `master` branch to the `master` branch that resides on the remote repository (known by your clone as `origin`). However, you're not allowed to do that, because you don't have write access to that remote repository.

You need to

1. either redefine the `origin` remote to be associated with your fork, by running

   ```
   git remote set-url origin https://github.com/RemiB/myrepo.git
   ```
2. or, if you want to preserve the original definition of the `origin` remote, define a new remote (called `myrepo`, here) that is associated to your fork:

   ```
   git remote add myrepo https://github.com/RemiB/myrepo.git
   ```

   Then you should be able to push your local `master` branch to your fork  by running

   ```
   git push myrepo master
   ```

   And if you want to tell Git that `git push` should push to `myrepo` instead of `origin` from now on, you should run

   ```
   git push -u myrepo master
   ```

instead.

Comment: will ´git push -u´ also change the default behavior of ´git pull´?

Comment: Yes it will, so instead of doing "push -u", you should use pushDefault option:

git config --add remote.origin.pushdefault myrepo

and it will only affect pushing, and applies to all existing an new branches.

Comment: Did `git remote set-url origin http://github.com/myname/reponame` and then `git push origin mybranch`. Worked! Thank you!

Comment: If add remote is used, how does it affect pull? Where does it pull from? How does it handle future merging between the 2 repos?

Comment: @KokHowTeh Adding another remote doesn't affect which remote branch (if any) a local branch tracks. However, `git push -u myrepo master` makes your local master start tracking `myrepo/master`. If, after that, you run `git pull` while on master, you will pull from `myrepo`, and no longer from `origin`.

Comment: These days on GH, you also have set up your PAT to the newly cloned repo. In your profile, go to "Settings", then "Developer settings" and add the cloned repo to your PAT or create a new PAT for the new repo

Answer (score 34):

So, you cloned someone's repo made the changes and then realized you can't push to that repo, but you can push to your own fork. So, you went ahead and forked the original repo.

All you have to do is swap the origin URL in your local clone with the URL of your forked repo.

Do it like this

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/fork/name.git
```

Where `https://github.com/fork/name.git` is the URL of your fork from the original repo.

After that, just

```
git push
```

and you'll be able to push your changes to your fork :)

Answer (score 11):

Okay I finally edited my git config file :

```
$ nano .git/config
```

changing :

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/<origin-project>/<origin-repo>.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

to

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/<mylogin>/<myrepo>.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Then,

```
$ git push
```

Worked like a charm.

Or, thanks to [Thiago F Macedo answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11368701/3197383) :

```
git remote set-url origin https://yourusername@github.com/user/repo.git
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SSH for authentication (instead of over HTTPS) then you can swap the origin URL in your local clone with the URL of your forked repo as follows:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repository
```

Then simply:

```
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd add for those using a jetbrains IDE (similar probably applies to others)
Git menu (via menu bar) -> Manage Remotes -> Edit the URL under the repo you want to change the origin location for to e.g. `https://github.com/your_git_handle/your_repo_name.git`

Answer (score -6):

You should clone the forked repo in your account first.

```
git clone https://github.com/your_account/repo.git
```

You absolutely have permissions to push to this repo. If you want to push your code to original repo, You can issue a pull request.

Comment: They are not asking to clone the fork. Kindly, read the question again.