# Pushing to a forked repo after clone from original

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project and I forked a repo from a team member who forked it from the original repo. He created a new branch with the same files and made changes in it.

However I cloned the original repo and worked on it and now I want to push the changes to my forked repo to the new branch he created. 
I went into the folder I made changes in, and I ran the following commands

```
git add .
git commit 
git push
```

and I got

> fatal: remote error: access denied ... /original-repo/project.git

I followed the instructions here: [How can I push to my fork from a clone of the original repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545613/how-can-i-push-to-my-fork-from-a-clone-of-the-original-repo)

but when I tried to run

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/xxx/project.git”
```

> I got “fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
>       fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have   the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Then I tried :

```
git remote add stash ssh://git@w.x.y.z:7999/xxx/project.git 
git push stash master
```

and I got

> ssh: connect to host w.x.y.z port 7999: Connection timed out

although I set up my ssh key and was able to ssh successfully

Finally I thought about adding my fork, so I ran

```
git remote add fork https://github.com/xxx/project
git push fork master
```

and it prompted me for my username and password, then I got the following:

> To https://github.com/xxx/project
>        ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
>       error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxx/project'
>       hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
>       hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
>       hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
>       hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>       hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

EDITS:

I ran

```
git pull origin master
```

and got

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

---

I ran

```
git pull github.com/xxx/project master
```

> fatal: 'github.com/xxx/project' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

I am really not sure what to do, I really appreciate any help

Comment: It's saying you need to do a pull to merge existing changes. git pull origin master and then try your push again.

Comment: Hello Dan, thank you for the attention. I updated the post

Comment: No problem, here is a good reference: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: Try setting origin with git remote add origin https://github.com/sara94/project.git

Comment: Either way, that is just for convenience.  Try "git pull https://github.com/sara94/project master" and then "git push https://github.com/sara94/project master"

Comment: I did that and it says "github.com/sara94/project" does not appear to be a git repository" although if I open "github.com/sara94/project" in the browser, it opens fine. I updated the post.

Comment: Okay, just checked your github account. You don't have any repositories. You need to create a new one and then that will give you an url to push to. Try creating one then I can help out further.

Comment: Hi Dan, I figured out what went wrong. I forked the repo and cloned it in a folder where my old clone from the original repo resides. So Alot of files got messed up, I am redoing everything to be sure. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For this error:

> ssh: connect to host w.x.y.z port 7999: Connection timed out

You need to indicate:

- You may not need ssh instruction
- Your github/gitlab username
- Your github/gitlab password. 
  In this way:

  > https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't pull to the fork.
You will have to merge the fork with you main/master/whatever_branch_name.

There is this topic about GitHub ssh keys

[Is it possible to have 2 (or more) GitHub accounts, 2 (or more) ssh key in one computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194174/is-it-possible-to-have-2-or-more-github-accounts-2-or-more-ssh-key-in-one-c)