# How to delete/change the remote origin master branch

Tags: eclipse, git, git-branch, git-clone, git-remote

I have a movile project repo in bitbucket and I cloned that repo into a eclipse project the remote branch master/origin point too that repo this is ok, but I created another empty repo in bitbucket and I want to push my project in that empty repo.

My problem is that when I do `git remote -v` it shows the name of the branches of the repo from were I cloned the project, I want to remove those branches and change them to use the branches of the new empty repo that I created

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545613/how-can-i-push-to-my-fork-from-a-clone-of-the-original-repo

Answer (score 1):

You can change `remote` of the repo to point to a different URL:

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:<your_id>/<new_repo.git>
```