# Git push failed on forked repository

Tags: git, github

'git push' command failed when I was trying to push a new file to a forked repository. The error I get is as follows:
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (permission denied)
I am the owner of the forked repository so I am not sure why I get this error. I appreciate help with that. tnx

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you're pushing to the right remote? Run the command `git remote -v` and confirm that the `origin` remote is a repository you have access to. If not, push to the remote you do have access to like:

```
git push -u <remote name> <branch name>
```

This will set your local branch up to track the given remote branch, so that `git push` will push to that by default. You may also need to change the setting of `push.default` if it has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the remote is your repository:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.git (push)
```

If that is not yours, change it like this:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

An then try to push again

```
$ git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps

git config --global --edit

Then add following to conf file

```
[credential]
  helper = osxkeychain
  useHttpPath = true
```

Comment: run git remote -v what you see ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your email privacy policy. And unCheck checkmark from "Keep my email addresses private".

Settings -> Emails

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
git push origin master
```

if this is the first time you're pushing to this forked repository

Comment: Have you checked out the fixes in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545613/how-can-i-push-to-my-fork-from-a-clone-of-the-original-repo)? Similar issue I think