# modified code push to another repository of remote server with git

Tags: git

- I cloned a repository from a remote server.
- Modified the codes.
- I forked the repository of the remote server.
- I want the modified codes on the forked repository.

How to achieve the result?

Comment: How did you achieve step 3? To me, the technical part of forking is implied by step 1 already. Also, which repository do you mean with "forked repository"? The one you forked from the the one you forked into?

Comment: Just add another repo and then push to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I push to my fork from a clone of the original repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545613/how-can-i-push-to-my-fork-from-a-clone-of-the-original-repo)

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem resolved by these steps below:

- git remote add forkRemoteServer
- git push --set-upstream nameOfForkRemoteServer