# How to solve, "error: failed to push some refs to"?

Tags: git, github

I was working on a branch called *main* that was based on a remote github repository that does not belong to me. Now, that I have added modifications to this local branch, I want to push it into a remote branch on github that belongs to me.

git status:

```
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
(venv)
```

git push --set-upstream origin <my_repository_name>

```
error: src refspec my_repository_name does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/username/my_repository_name.git'
```

**NOTE:**

After applying Marcelo's suggestion, I attempted to push to the forked version of the repository and I still received the error message:

```
remote: Permission to username/my_repository_name.git denied to username.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/my_repository_name.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

**UPDATE1:**

git remote -v

```
myrepo  https://github.com/username/my_repository_name.git (fetch)
myrepo  https://github.com/username/my_repository_name.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/username/my_repository_name.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/username/my_repository_name.git (push)
upstream        https://github.com/someone_else/my_repository_name.git (fetch)
upstream        https://github.com/someone_else/my_repository_name.git (push)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to [fork](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo) the github repo and add the changes you want to make?

Comment: I thought I did it and I already made lot of changes :(

Comment: If you forked the repo and its the repo you're working with, why not just `push` the changes? It's not going to modify the original repo, if you did in fact fork the original repo correctly.

Comment: Probably I didn't fork it and that's why push is not working.

Comment: You could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25546211/11286032)?

Comment: The second step gives me error remote: Permission to username/some_remote_branch.git denied to username.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/some_remote_branch/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: Will you provide more details about how you arrived at this situation? When you say "I was working on a branch called development", how did you create the repository that this branch is in? Did you `git clone` a repo from Github? Or did you `git init` a new repo? Or something else? If you did a `git clone`, then what repo did you clone?

Comment: Some of this can be determined from the command `git remote -v`. What is the output of this command?

Comment: I redid the whole thing from fresh by creating a fork on my account and then changed some stuff to push to my version. I updated the post. By development, I just mean "main" in here.

Comment: And I git cloned the repo and then changed the main branch.

Comment: I git clone this repo: https://github.com/username/my_repository_name.git

Answer (score -2):

This error occurs when your local branch is not updated with the remote branch changes. Try

```
git pull <remote> <branch>
```

to update remote changes first, then push your local branch commits to the remote. There may be conflicts that you will need to rectify manually.

Comment: what will be my <remote> and <branch>?

Comment: name of your remote, which is generally set to origin.

Comment: name of the branch you want to set in the remote, it can be same or different from the local branch name

Comment: Have you logged in with correct credentials?