# Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal

Tags: git, github, git-push

I want to push README.md to Github.
Using Ubuntu 14.04LTS
So, I commit in the following steps.

```
echo "# test" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
git push -u origin master
```

But, below error occurred.

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/user/repo.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I know solve this error this way

```
git remote set-url origin https://username@github.com/user/repo.git
```

In this way , I must enter password.

```
$ git push origin master
Password:
```

But I hate to enter password.

I have checked this, but I don't solved.
[Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)

Please tell me how to push without password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to either use https and enter your password or use ssh (and associate your public ssh key to your github account)

Comment: thank you for answering.  

why I can't use https without password?
Until a little while ago, I can use https without password.

Comment: You can pull from https without password if you clone a repo as read-only (i.e without username), but you can't push to a https repo without password unless you use password catching: https://help.github.com/articles/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password/

Comment: Thank you verymuch.
Probably, I can’t push from multiple devices.
Because , I need do this  

    git remote add origin https://username@github.com/user/repo.git

Probably,I can't push this remote   

    git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git

Comment: If you use a ssh remote you need to add the public key of each user in each device in order to push. If you use https you don't have to do that but you will have to enter the password (at least once per session if you use a cache with a long timeout).

Comment: how to do you the things in ur answer? Can you provide some code or commands to execute?

Comment: Check the set-url option on the question @CharlieParker

Answer (score 12):

This may solve your problem:

```
git remote set-url origin https://username:userpwd@github.com/user/repo.git
```

Comment: @JanDoggen This is not a link-only answer, if you look closer to answer, you see that dilei gives the answer of question not a link.

Comment: @Yusuf Got it. And (s)he should still explain *why* this may solve the problem. 'Code only' answer are also valued low on this site.

Comment: @JanDoggen 403 error means authorization issue, so this answer send username and password on remote url and there is no more 403 error for that.

Comment: Gleeful bashing of budding new user aside **this and nothing else** is what worked for me. However, this will cause your password to be stored **in plain text** in your .git directory. I suggest setting remote URL to `https://username@github.com/user/repo.git`, and using more suitable means to cache your password if desired. 

This issue occurred for me after changing my github username. I can't for the life of me find a way to change the password git tried to use for the remote, but *dilei's answer works*.

Comment: yeah +1 on this fixing my problem.  .git-credentials was being ignored for me on whatever git version is on this centos6 box, and this fix allowed me to get on with it.  entirely enough information here to be usable.

Answer (score 4):

I believe one of the main reasons of this happening is because of bad login credentials from your local machine to the server.

If I remember correctly, one has to

(1) Make sure you have a stable git version

(2) Ensure the remote is correct

(3) Provide access token if 2FA is enabled

(4) Checking your permissions(username/password)

(5) Use ssh instead of https

[Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313) might come in handy, which has a lot of extra information regarding your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using multiple github accounts then that could also be the cause of the problem. Git saves the username and password you use first in your OS's credential vault. Any subsequent requests will be using those details regardless of what your IDE tells you.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is the result of a changing a repo (resulting in a username, password mismatch), try this at the command line:

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
[Press Return]
```

it will prompt you for your username and password.

See https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with a *clone* or *fork*, double-check that the repository URL you're trying to push to is your *fork's* URL instead of the original owner's repository URL.

```
git remote -v
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error

```
Error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing
```

For example: `https://github.com/Joey-project/repo.git/info/refs fatal: HTTP request failed`

and then **resolved** it by the following method:

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Open User Accounts
3. Open Credentials Manager
4. Open Windows Credentials

Now in the **Generic Credentials** Tab see the **GitHub/(any other host) credentials** then edit your **username** and/or **password** to their correct states.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your git client and you should not get this issue anymore