# How to push code to someone else repository from visual studio

Tags: github, git-push

I have made a react native project on visual studio code. I want to push this project to someone else's git repo.

I did the following:

`git remote add origin https://github.com/aasthaverma1212/Android_Project.git`

`git branch -M main`

`git push -u origin main`

It gave me error that `remote: Permission to XXXXXXX/Android_Project.git denied to pXXXXXXXX4. fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/XXXXXXX/Android_Project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

I even tried to do `git config --global user.email 'XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com'`
And then again I did `git push -u origin main`

It still gives me the same error.

Comment: Is the repository public? If not, make sure the owner gave your git account permission to push to that repo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996017/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal)