# Git log out user from command line

Tags: git

Is there a command for logging out of git? I'm turning my computer over to somebody else and don't want the git to be attached to my account in the terminal.

Comment: What operating system are you on?  How about just wiping your hard disk?

Comment: I'm on OS X. I'd like to hand over my computer without wiping everything. I just don't want personal information, repositories accessible.

Comment: Is wiping your home directory an option?  It typically contains a whole lot of personal information, which will be hard to get rid of completely.

Comment: 0_o `git` doesn't really have a conception of "logged in" or "logged out". If you didn't log in to something, you generally can't log out of it, either.

Comment: @bydr Configure fast user switching and switch to guest user before handing your laptop over.

Comment: You could also just change your password on github/bitbucket/whatever website you use.

Comment: I tried everything to try to log out of git then my colleague pointed out I'd signed in using an app password, so I'd need to revoke that app password to stop access to GIT on that server. Once I did this, 'git pull' stopped working, which is what I wanted :)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Remove your SSH keys from `~/.ssh` (or where you stored them).

Remove your user settings:

```
git config --global --unset user.name
git config --global --unset user.email
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

Or all your global settings:

```
git config --global --unset-all
```

Maybe there's something else related to the credentials store, but I always used git over SSH.

Comment: This really depends on the OS, and on the credential store used.  In general, it will be difficult to completely make sure you don't leak any secrets.

Comment: This did not work for me. If you are in a corporate environment, privileges vary. I had to manually remove a stale credential from the Windows Vault. See my response below.

Comment: For me `git config --global --unset-all` outputs `error: wrong number of arguments, should be from 1 to 2` ?

Comment: `git config --global --unset credential.helper` Do this as the above comment is not working

Comment: The commands above depend on the version of git. I've recently update my version of git, and I have to use devDeejay answer.

Comment: This does not work on git version 2.32.0

Answer (score 217):

I came across this same problem, and the above answer didn't work for me because [github](https://github.com/) was being fed my credentials through windows credential manager instead of git bash.

You may have to check windows credential manager and delete the github entry under `control panel > user accounts > credential manager > Windows credentials > Generic credentials`

Comment: This solution fixed my issues on Windows 10 with error 403 while I am trying to use HTTPS protocol and two different usernames.

I think the problem stems from the Git Desktop Client. I don't use it at home, and I have no issues there. Here at the office, I couldn't push to my personal repo.

Blowing out the Windows credentials via the above steps seems to have done the trick. It also caused the Git login window to load when I did `git push`, so that's why I suspect the Desktop Client.

Comment: `git config --global --unset credential.helper` works great. I couldn't find the login in credential manager as mentioned.

Comment: To access Windows credentials see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026814/windows-accessing-credential-manager.

Comment: Git/github is the most un-intuitive tool on earth.

Answer (score 36):

On a Mac, credentials are stored in Keychain Access. Look for Github and remove that credential. More info: https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/

Comment: If it will not delete from search:

Find it in the list without searching and then delete them!

That should solve your issue, there is a bug in the search option.



Please check the padlock against the keychain item list on the far left is unlocked, locked items will not delete.

Answer (score 21):

Try this on Windows:

```
cmdkey /delete:LegacyGeneric:target=git:https://github.com
```

Answer (score 20):

If you are facing any issues during push ( in windows OS), just remove the cached git account by following the given steps below:

1. Search for Control panel and open the same.
2. Search for Credential Manager and open this.
3. Click on Windows Credentials under Manage your credentials page.
4. Under Generic Credentials click on GitHub.
5. Click on Remove and then confirm by clicking Yes button.
6. Now start pushing the code and you will get GitHub popup to login again and now you are done. Everything will work properly after successful login.

Answer (score 17):

I am in a corporate setting and was attempting a simple `git pull` after a recent change in password.

I got: `remote: Invalid username or password.`

Interestingly, the following did not work: `git config --global --unset credential.helper`

I use Windows-7, so, I went to control panel -> Credential Manager -> Generic Credentials.

From the credential manager list, delete the line items corresponding to git.

After the deletion, come back to gitbash and git pull should prompt the dialog for you to enter your credentials.

Comment: +1 Exactly what i was looking for. Except it was in Windows Credentials instead of Generic Credentials for my windows 8.

Answer (score 14):

I could not clone a repository due to being logged on with other credentials.

To switch to another user, I did:

```
git config --global --unset user.name
git config --global --unset user.email
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

Then I cloned not with the ssh URL, but with the https url.
It asked for credentials and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

In my case none of these solutions worked (not even the manual removal of `~/.gitconfig`), so I had to rename the local repo folder (to avoid losing local changes) and `git clone` the remote repo again...