# How to log out of old git account on windows CMD

Tags: windows, git, github

I know you can do git config user.name but that doesnt actually log you into a different account. it doesnt ask for your password. im trying to push to my git but it's giving me a 403 access denied and then telling me i'm logged onto my old git account.

How do I change it?

Answer (score 0):

These two SO questions should help you out:

1. [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)
2. [Git log out user from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238037/git-log-out-user-from-command-line)

If not, check out [this link](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/error-403-in-response-to-git-push-u-origin-master).