# "log out" from old github account and use other one for smartgit

Tags: git, smartgit

For some obscure reason it doesnt seem straightforward to change of account in smartgit:
I had an old account that I would like not to use to commit things in another repo. Despite removing everything in Edit->Preferences->Authentification Smartgit is still not asking me for new credentials ... I don't know what I am missing here

Comment: Take a look there https://stackoverflow.com/a/37450495/1951947

Answer (score 2):

Check **Edit|Preferences**, section **Hosting Provider**, **GitHub** here: you most likely will have **Use OAuth token for repository authentication** selected. This makes SmartGit authenticate for *any* of your GitHub repositories with its application access token, so it won't ask for repository-specific credentials anymore.

To solve your problem, just reconfigure the **GitHub** hosting provider for your new account.