# Merging two git clients

Tags: git

I recently installed a clean copy of windows 10 on my machine and installed git. I configured git username but when i cloned my own repository, a VS code extension says it was edited by "Muremwa" instead of "you". How do I make git know that it's the same user?

Comment: How did you configure your git username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the **git username** for the current repository using:

```
git config user.name
```

To check the **e-mail id** for the user use:

```
git config user.email
```

To **change** it you can use:

```
git config user.name "Mona Lisa"

git config user.email "email@example.com"
```

To set it **globally** use `--global` .

Example:

```
git config --global user.email "email@example.com"
```

For more info check:

- [Setting username in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/)
- [Setting Email in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git/)

Comment: I actually did all that. It's only the VS code extension with that recognizes the contributors as two diffrent people.

Comment: see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318673/changing-the-git-user-inside-visual-studio-code