# Visual Studio Code and git : Permission denied to X

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, permissions, settings

I have 2 github account X (professional one) and Y (personal one).

On my personal computed, I used both account, with Visual Code.

But now, when I try to push some changes to my repository, I have a message :

> Permission to Y/repo.git denied to X.

---

It's a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318673/changing-the-git-user-inside-visual-studio-code), but the answer there are not working for me.

I tried :

`git config --global user.email "email@example.com"`

Didn't work. I tried without `--global`, didn't work.

I also saw [this answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/70044), but I have no idea how to 'un-blacklist' a file. Anyway I can't even find my `.gitconfig`.

---

I'm loosing patience and hope, if anyone has a solution to this, I will be very grateful for sharing !

Comment: Skip VSC for a bit. Can you access your repository with command line git?

Comment: I was using terminal of visual code with git as command line. I tried with the window terminal, but I have the same error...

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40907049/9494790) solved it. Finally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem. @Astariul's comment worked for me. I'll post it here for visibility. He linked to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40907049/9494790

Basically, an old Git login is being stored in Windows and needs to be deleted. Go to Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Manage your credentials, delete all the ones involving Git and VS Code, then restart VS Code.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue on my machine by signing out of the account I was logged into on vs-code by using the Accounts button on the left side bar. I had to go through the login process again with the trusted account.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add to this for future reference.

I was experiencing the same issue. However, that was because I added the remote using the SSH `git@` style URL instead of the `https://` URL. That made my computer try to authenticate using my SSH keys instead of my login credentials.

Since I didn't have the SSH keys on my machine, it would never work. Once I removed and re-add the remote using `git remote add origin https://github.com/<link-to-my-repo>` then it prompted me to login on my browser to authenticate, and everything worked as expected!

Hope this helps someone else in the future!