# VS Code: Get 'Bad credentials' when using Clone Repository

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I use vscode version 1.45.1. I get 'Bad credentials' when using Clone Repository. Lately I changed my username at github. That could be the reason. How do I tell vs code that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the git user inside Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318673/changing-the-git-user-inside-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to open up `Credential Manager` in Windows and delete (or edit) the Github account there:

[image: Windows Credential Manager]

You'll need to restart Visual Studio Code for it to prompt you to login to Github again.

Also note that you may need to revoke the OAuth connection in Github under https://github.com/settings/applications:

[image: Github OAuth for VSCode]

Answer (score 2):

Had the same on a MacBook Pro. Signing out via the profile button (Bottom left), closing VSCODE and reopening it while trying to connect to GitHub worked for me. Hope this helps others.

Comment: Great. worked for ubuntu too.