# Multiple GitHub users for VSCode GitHub Codespaces extension

Tags: vscode-extensions, github-codespaces

I work in/with several GitHub accounts. I would like to use a single VSCode desktop installation on Mac to connect to (or create) GitHub Codespaces in the different GitHub accounts.

However, I have only ever managed to connect to a single GitHub account in the VSCode GitHub Codespaces extension.

How do I resolve this?

I've tried un-installing and re-installing the extension but the credentials to the original account are retained when doing this.

After being connected to the first GitHub account, using the VSCode command Codespaces: Sign in does nothing.

Comment: you may want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625513/i-have-2-github-accounts-how-can-i-use-both-when-i-am-working-in-vs-code