# vscode setting git path which inside"user settings json" file

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have the problem following the [solution website](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/git-not-found-install-it-or-configure-it-in-vscode), to solve setting git path for vscode

- vscode "user settings json" file

```
{
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false

}
```

I'm confusing with add git path on it

```
{
   // enable Git in VS Code
  "git.enabled": true,

  // point to the Git executable
  "git.path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe"
}
```

cause however I put, I always see the error output

---

I'm using windows, and below is git version and environment

```
C:\Users\jason>where git
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

C:\Users\jason>git --version
git version 2.41.0.windows.1
```

---

main issue:
now in vscode terminal, I can't cd to `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` file
to set my git info

```
git config --global user.email y*********@gmail.com         
git config --global user.name Y*********
```

therefore, I might need to set git path(in vscode ) which inside"user settings json" file

- the 3rd time I tried , input `git config --g.....` is not working

console:
[image: demo pic01]
output:
[image: demo pic02]

Comment: What error output? What platform are you on? Is git installed? Where is git installed?

Comment: windows, "git version 2.41.0.windows.1" , located "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe"

 ----> 
solving "git error",  Make sure you configure your 'user.name' and 'user.email' in git in VS code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the Git user inside Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318673/changing-the-git-user-inside-visual-studio-code)

Comment: that were the Initial questions, I also did the `git config --global user.email y*********@gmail.com
git config --global user.name Y*********` but before that , I need to set git path correctly,  which lead to this advanced questions.

Comment: The git path is set correctly?

Comment: thanks for providing discussion, but I'm dealing with one step further

Comment: What does that mean? One step further from what? The error _"Make sure you configure your 'user.name' and 'user.email' in git in VS code"_ can be solved by following the link I gave

Comment: yes @evolutionxbox , I just follow the  solution website ,need to set like this format, linux,mac don't have to

Comment: should say that, now in vscode terminal, I can't cd to `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` file to set my git info `git config --global user.email y*********@gmail.com git config --global user.name Y*********`, therefore, I might need to set git path(in vscode ) which inside"user settings json" file

Comment: If you type `git --version` into your terminal do you also get an error? (Inside vscode and outside please)

Comment: in vscode type `git --version` [online pic](https://imgur.com/eyYH83k) , don't get error output

Comment: I'm confused about what the root problem and goal are here. setting git.path in VS Code is for VS Code's builtin Git functionality, but AFAIK, doesn't affect the `PATH` environment variable in the integrated terminal (it technically could do that, but my gut thinks it doesn't)

Comment: hello @starbal , cause what I know from tutorial, I need to cd to `cd to C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` to set my git info `git config --global user.email y*********@gmail.com git config --global user.name Y*********`  , now I **can't**  simply cd to that path, so, I'm setting the git path in vscode now. I think ur suggestion is focus on doing  `git config --global user.email y*********@gmail.com git config --global user.name Y*********`, or not affect, but I'm just not sure how to do so

Comment: you shouldn't need to cd to there to perform that configuration change.

Comment: I just post the img, can you take a look, I think I just follow ur suggestion but not work

Comment: 1) windows environment doesn't have `which`. use `where.exe` 2) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541