# How to manage github credentials with Windows 10?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, windows-10

I often need to switch from a github account to another (professional / personnal) to clone a repo locally and then publish modifications to an other.
I'm logged in github via VSCode and cannot switch from an account to an other : when I log out and then log in, the same github account is used.

I need to browse Windows parameters to delete credentials here :

[image: Windows Credentials manager]

Is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: related (maybe one of the answers there helps?): [Changing the Git user inside Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42318673/11107541)

Comment: is settings sync enabled? If it is, what if you disable it and then try to switch accounts? (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128718). try also seeing if anything in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aopen+label%3Aauthentication+label%3Abug matches your issue. maybe https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/104399 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is a special setting that will store the credentials on a per-repo basis instead of per site](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-your-personal-account/managing-multiple-accounts#contributing-to-multiple-accounts-using-https-and-personal-access-tokens).

You may need to clear any previously stored credentials first though:

Run `git config --get credential.helper`, then depending on the output:

- `manager` or `manager-core`: run the following command:

  ```
  echo "protocol=https`nhost=github.com" | git credential-manager erase
  ```
- `wincred`: run the following command:

  ```
  cmdkey /delete:LegacyGeneric:target=git:https://github.com
  ```

Or manually delete all the credentials from your Windows Credential Manager.

### Configure the credential manager for per-repo tokens

Then run the following command to instruct github to use the whole clone URL instead of just the domain to store credentials:

```
git config --global credential.https://github.com.useHttpPath true
```

Now re-authenticate to GitHub, your credentials should be stored on a per-repo basis. It means you'll get a few more credential prompts after the switch, but after a while you'll have a token stored per repo and won't need to switch at all anymore.

This assumes you are using the [**Git Credential Manager**, which can be downloaded from here](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/releases).

### Add the User to the clone url

If I'm remembering correctly, you should also be able to add the desired username to your clone url:

```
git clone https://jessehouwing@github.com/jessehouwing/my-repo
```

Should store a separate credential than the one it stored for:

```
git clone https://astranger@github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager
```

You can update the current remote for your repo and add the user in:

```
git remote --verbose
origin  https://github.com/owner/repo (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/owner/repo (push)

# Take the full url from the output and add your user:
git remote --set-url origin https://yourdesireduser@github.com/owner/repo
```