# Make VS Code ask for GitHub credentials

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github, credentials

I'm trying to push to a Github Gist repository. If I do it from a GNOME terminal, it asks me for credentials and I enter my Github username and a token generated from https://github.com/settings/tokens and it works fine. If I do it from a VS Code terminal, it doesn't ask for credentials, but returns an error:

```
remote: Permission to write to gist denied.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gist.github.com/.../.../': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Presumably this error in VS Code terminal and not in GNOME terminal is caused by VS Code storing credentials, but I can't figure out how to delete Github credentials stored in VS Code, so that I can enter the new token and push successfully. How do I delete these Github credentials in VS Code or make VS Code ask for them otherwise?

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, VS Code Version: 1.85.1

Comment: I assume you're using Linux... please tell us which distribution and version you're using. Do you have the GitHub VS Code extension installed, or are you using VS Code's built-in terminal to run commands manually?

Comment: See question edit for version numbers. I get this error when I use the VS Code built-in terminal, and also when I run `Git: Push` through the VS Code command pallette, or the equivalent through the VS Code version control GUI

Comment: Are you using git's credential helper? https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git

Comment: What happens when you run `git config --global` from within VS Code - and how does it compare to the output from your normal terminal/shell?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, I am not using git's credential helper. `git config --global --list` just displays my username and password, both in GNOME and in VS Code terminal

Answer (score 0):

Following advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64368765/8477566), click the "Accounts" icon in the bottom left (above the "Manage" settings cog/gear icon), select " (GitHub)", "Sign Out" (confirm), then open the command palette, enter "Git: Push", when asked to allow the extension to sign into GitHub, select "Cancel", then in the authentication dialog at the top of the VS Code screen, enter **GitHub username** (not email address), and **Personal access token** (not password) to allow pushing to a GitHub Gist repository