# change remote repo for a project forked from github on local machine (Rstudio)

Tags: git, github, rstudio

This question seems obvious, but I can't seem to find a direct answer in my searching of stackoverflow and other corners of the internet.

I have a project I work on using R studio on a local machine. The project started by pulling from a repo on Github. I can't push to this repo, as its not mine and I don't have permission. No big deal, I'd like to create a new repository on github to save all my changes to the original repo and the current state of the project. I can't just enter:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/new_repo.git
```

Because there is already a remote origin. I receive this error:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

Right. This is clear. The origin is the original github repository that I pulled this from, and also the one I am not allowed to update because its not my code. Straightforward. I want to change the origin of the repository to: `https://github.com/user/new_repo.git` (the new repo I just setup on github), but save all of the work history of how I have modified the project.

Apologies if this is a duplicate and I don't understand the other responses to similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using advice from @manishrw, and several other posts. I needed to do several things:

*First,* 
I needed to change the origin remote url in the `.git/config` file. This could be accomplished as detailed by @manishrw, and the actual URL filepath needed to be `ssh://git@github.com/user/new_repo.git`. So, from the home directory you would enter:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/user/new_repo.git
```

So far so good. However, I still had problems, as I was working from a remote computer which had never been authenticated. I would get the error:

```
Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

*Second,* To solve this I had to setup my username and email for github on the remote machine, and then generate an SSH key. I followed instructions [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/rstudio-pushing-to-github-with-ssh-authentication/), which I summarize below:

1. Set username and email at the shell within R studio. These are your github.com username and email.

   git config --global user.name "your_username"
   git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"
2. In RStudio, go to menu Tools / Global options / Git SVN
3. Click "Create RSA key..." and follow instructions. You can set a password here, but its not necessary.
4. Click "view public key" and copy the key.
5. Copy the key to your Github account setting (Edit profile / SSH keys / Add SSH key).

To check that ssh-authentication works, try to run

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

and you should get something like

```
Hi your_username! You’ve successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Everything should now work awesome.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
git remote set-url origin newurl
```

**EDIT**:

When you clone with the git read-only address (mostly when you don't log in), then you don't get read+write access.

Repository needs to change the way it pushes using ssh. Follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7771927/4927688) to change your repo config on your PC to ssh way.

Comment: I did this, but when I go to push I get this error: `error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/user/new_repo.git/info/refs`

Comment: If you could change the question, to aptly describe the question, it would be helpful to others too!

Comment: I made the changes to the config file as instructed in the other post. I now get this error when I go to push: `Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`