# Why is it that when clone or pull in gitlab onpremise there is always an addition of slash(/) to the last character of the repo URL?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

Hi everyone i have problem when clone or pull in gitlab onpremise like this

```
git clone https://gitlab.example.net/webapps/baseservice.git
Cloning into 'baseservice'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.example.net/webapps/baseservice.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

by the way i'm using gitlab docker container (Gitlab CE version v16.0.3) and pointing subdomain using apache2.4 vhost reserve proxy. This script of apache vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName gitlab.example.net
   Redirect permanent / https://gitlab.example.net
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/wildcard.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/wildcard.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/certs/wildcard_bundle_ca.crt

  ServerName gitlab.example.net
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://123.456.1.234:10080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://123.456.1.234:10080/

  ProxyRequests     Off
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
</VirtualHost>
```

thanks for help I'll apreciate , sorry for my English

Comment: `/` at the end of URL is valid character. Why you think it's causing issues? Maybe you are not authorized or URL is wrong (indicated by status code **403**)?

Comment: @Justinas thanks for quick reply, my account role is owner of the project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gitlab runner The requested URL returned error: 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006690/gitlab-runner-the-requested-url-returned-error-403)

Comment: That does not mean you are actually adding credentials where it's needed.

Comment: issue solved : my ip public of web server has banned by gitlab container :)