# How to use the correct git account in git push?

Tags: git, github

Whenever I type:

```
git push
```

I get:

```
remote: Permission to [username]/[project-name].git denied to [old-username].
Fatal: unable to access [https://github.com/link/.git]: the requested url returned error: 403
```

I think that git tries to push using `[old-username]` which is a github account I don't use for this project.

I'm new to git but I can't seem to find the solution. How can I get github to prompt me for my correct username and password so I can push to the remote branch my new account has access to?

Comment: git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com

Comment: Doesn't  work. I should note that (Because I didn't notice it) one of my previous commits were done under my old username / mail. But my newest commit is done under my new name / mail

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7438313/5784831) help?

Comment: No, I think that is for a different issue and it recommends the use of ssh. For now I decided to unset my credential helper using

"git config --global --unset credential.helper"

I'm not sure if this will wipe my old credentials as well (hopefully), but I will figure that out on a later schedule. In the meantime I will just manually input everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your remote url to include your username and/or password

```
git remote origin set-url https://username@github.com/username/repository.git
```

With also your password

```
git remote origin set-url https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```