# unable to push to github using the command : git push -u origin master

Tags: git, github

I'm unable to push the project to github using the following command in cmd:git push -u origin master

> remote: Permission to shashank136/Django_polling_App.git denied to rishidada136.
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/shashank136/Django_polling_App.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

my github account is using the id shashank136.sk@gmail.com

any idea how to fix this error.I'm new to Github

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)

Comment: They have extensive and very user fiendly [help](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/)

Answer (score 0):

There are different possibilities why you are not getting access to the repo:

1) First ensure that the remote is correct:

```
git remote -v
```

Verify that it points to the correct github repo

2) Make sure that your username and email in git config are right using

```
git config user.email
```

If they are different from your github account, correct them using

```
git config user.email "<your email associated with github">
```

3) Make sure your password is correct:
   You can update your password using:

```
git config --global user.password
git remote set-url origin https://yourusername@github.com/<user-name>/<repo-name>.git
```