# permission denied to user while pushing the changes (changing git local account)

Tags: git, github

I am trying to commit some changes from my local repository to my GitHub, but when I am trying to `PUSH` the changes, I am getting this error:

> remote: Permission to vivek/abc.git denied to vivekstudent.
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/viveksinghggits/bethere.git/':   The requested URL returned error: 403

I believe I am getting this error because I am logged into my local git through another account. How can I reset the settings so that I can `PUSH` the changes to the remote?
The answer that is tagged as possible duplicate doesnt actually addressed the problem that I am facing here, that question is about the protocol that is used to PUSH the changes but my issue is with the account I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)

Comment: @DanLowe that answer is not useful, in my case what I think is that I configured another name(vivekstudent) and emailid earlier some time and now I am trying to `PUSH` the code to my another github account(viveksinghggits).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should change the title to something more relevant, like
*How to change git local account*
anyhow according to the [docs](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git/) you need to change the email account asosiated with the git installation
first check what email/account you are using

```
$ git config --global user.email
wrong@example.com
```

then change it by

```
$ git config --global user.email "correct.email@example.com"
```

If you want to do this for just one repository omit the `--global` option

Comment: I have already tried changing the user.name and email but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, set your username and email:

```
$ git config --global user.name
$ git config --global user.email
```

Then push like this:

```
git push https://github.com/viveksinghggits/bethere HEAD:master
```