# how to allow multiple users to pull to same repo

Tags: git

Currently I have an entry like this in my `.git/config` file:

```
url = https://LarryMartell@github.com/...
```

When I pull it prompts me for a password. What I want is for it to prompt me for both a username and password so multiple people can pull. If I remove the `LarryMartell` from the url in the config file I get a `403 Forbidden`

Here is my git config file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = https://LarryMartell@github.com/...
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: You get the 403; do other people going to `https://github.com/...` get the 403? Is there something else in your git configuration that keeps a username around that may cause the 403?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed help?

Comment: NB: usually, it's `pull from` and `push to`. I think you mean `pull from`; just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Everyone gets the 403. I added the entire config file to the question. That other question says to change from http to ssh. I tried that and get `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: The publickey message indicates one should upload their public ssh key to GitHub. Possibly not what you immediately want to do.

Comment: No I want each user to have to enter their creds from the command line for every pull

Comment: Using https usually works for me, but I don't have a `[remote]` section in my git config: I clone directly from GitHub (in case of a private repo), and that seems to set things up correctly.

Comment: "I want each user to have to enter their creds from the command line for every pull": seems a bit odd. Can I ask why, out of curiosity?

Comment: This is for our production deployment. Multiple people are allowed to do deployments. I know could create some global user that everyone knows the password for, but I did not think having git prompt for the username would be this difficult.

Comment: My curiosity is actually: why bother your users with having to enter their credentials every time? I assume each user is independent, and can therefore have their own private/public key pair. I'm not saying you should do this, but as a user, I would be annoyed having to enter my user/password each time (and an accidental keylogger would love this). There is, of course `[credential]\n  helper = cache --timeout=86400` in `.gitconfig` for that.

Comment: Can you clone the repository over https without the user-name in the url?

Comment: Additionally, what is your `git` version?

Comment: Git version is 1.7.1. Yes I can clone the repo over https without the user-name in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, upgrade your git version.

Most answers on the internet (StackOverflow largely), suggest to do exactly as you do now, with the username in the URL. More recent versions of git allow what you want.

I would close this as a duplicate of, for example, [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed) , but you'd have to scroll down to the eight answer to find the suggestion to upgrade git. The top answers suggest either the ssh route, or the https://@github.com route.

That eight answer provides a link to GitHub's help page on this as well: [https cloning errors](https://help.github.com/articles/https-cloning-errors/)

Quoting from that:

> There's no minimum Git version necessary to interact with GitHub, but we've found version 1.7.10 to be a comfortable stable version that's available on many platforms

I'll have to assume that "comfortable stable" here means that you can do what you want with this version.

---

If you can't or don't want to upgrade, I'm afraid you're stuck with the current work-arounds, as older git versions simply don't seem to support this.

Comment: I am on CentOS 6.5 that comes with git version 1.7.1. I tried to build  2.14.1 from source but that failed with `/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL PREFIX='/usr/local' INSTALL_BASE='' --localedir='/usr/local/share/locale'
Can't locate ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at Makefile.PL line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 3.`

Comment: @LarryMartell That error is searchable, and otherwise a different, new question.

Comment: Yes, googled error, installed perl-devel, then was able to build, and now it works as desired, prompting for username and password on command line. Thanks so much!