# cant push android studio project to Github, getting error 403

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

Previously I have successfully added projects to Github from android studio but now I can't. I have followed this website for GitHub and worked fine:
https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/#comment-32683

Steps are:
 1. create a new git repo.
 2. from android studio- VCS> Import into version control> create git repo.
 3. In windows root directory of project open bash command and type > git remote add origin https://github.com/xxx/myProject.git 
 4. then back to android studio and a)project>Git>add
 b)project>Git>Commit 
c) project>Git>repository>push

these steps worked fine and I used to get a successful message. But now I am getting error 403 at the final stage where i am trying to push the project.

Why is this happening and how to solve it?

## **Update:**

I have tried with two different github accounts. With one I can push sucessfully and with another I can't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)

Answer (score 1):

> A web server may return an HTTP 403 Forbidden status in response to a
>   request from a client for a web page or it may indicate that the
>   server can be reached and process the request but refuses to take any
>   further action. HTTP status code 403 responses are the result of the
>   web server being configured to deny access to the requested resource
>   by the client.

Hence, you don't have the tight to access the server for some reason. Try to check the access permissions on GitHub project page if it's yours, or ask the owner.

Comment: It's my own github account and I have tried to find the permissions but all seemed fine. Still if you please give me the specific direction on where I should look for permission or edit them then that would be great.