# GitHub - unable to push changes

Tags: github

I cloned a repo and created a new branch without problem.

When try to push changes to a new branch - getting error:

```
git push origin new-branch

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.....git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

What can be a problem and how to resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have write access to the repo. The branch you created is probably only local.

Comment: Thanks. Should someone (e.g. Admin of this repo) give access particularly for me for this repo?

Comment: Did you clone or fork?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fork the repo first then clone your fork. Since you are not the contributor you will get 403 Error.

Comment: Completely omitted that. Thanks.