# Git returning Error 403 while pushing the code

Tags: git, github

Everything was working fine, until I create a new GitHub account.
When I try to push the code for first time to github server with new account, following error is occurring:

```
remote: Permission to NEW_USER/NEW_REPO.git denied to OLD_USER.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/NEW_USER/NEW_REPO/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Tried to reset remote url using:

`$git remote set-url origin https://username@github.com/user/repo.git` ... but not working.

Got one solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26842919), but for Mac OS. Any ideas how to resolve this. 
Using `git bash version 2.16.1.windows.4.`

*Thanks*

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This happens when two git accounts are being used on same machine.
On Windows 7 you need to remove git Credentials from Windows vault.

- go to Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Manage your credentials.
- Under Generic Credentials delete entries for github credentials.
- Try to push code and this time it will prompt you for correct username and password again.

[image]

Comment: To complete this aswer for mac users. go to Keychain > Search git > Right Click on github/gitlab/etc  creditional > Delete > then username and password will be asked again and problem will be solved

Answer (score 6):

You may check for the [Git Credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) you are using, and change that with your new account.

As the top answer from the question you mentioned says, using a SSH way by

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:new_user/new_repo.git
```

(and set the SSH Key) instead of HTTPS way is also a workaround.

Comment: Credentials are correct. Somehow it's still referring to old git account user name.
Between how to set SSH key ?

Comment: Or any repo-based credential exists? Set the SSH Key contains the step of "Generating a SSH Key" and "Register a SSH Key to a GitHub account".