# Cant push code from windows computer to git repository

Tags: git

I created a GitHub account and then a repository named who-dare-wins. Then in command prompt I clone the by using `git clone https://github.com/MidhuCherian/who-dare-wins.git`. After that I add the files using `git add .`, then commit by using `git commit -m "commit"`.Then I tried to push the code to remote repository by using `git push -u origin master`,but it showing an error as follows:

```
remote: Permission to MidhuCherian/who-dare-wins.git denied to MidhuJames.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/MidhuCherian/who-dare-wins.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

How can I rectify my error?

Comment: The `403` is indicating that it is forbidden (as I am sure you're aware too). Try using SSH instead; I strongly believe will work. Just in case you're not sure how: https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

It should work with HTTPS though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+The+requested+URL+returned+error%3A+403

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this message because of --global email and name problems. to solve this problem, before `git push` use the following two commands given below

```
git config --global user.name Your Name
git config --global user.email yourmail@gmail.com
```

here email that is used by you to make your Github account. You can find out your email at git hub sittings tab. 
 now finally use `git push` to commit your changes in the online repository.

If you still fail and **403 error** then you should use **SSH**(*shell command*) for pushing data into GitHub