# access denied when using two accounts in github

Tags: git, github, multi-user

i have two accounts in github my own account (some public repos) in my pc and my company's account (private repos) in my computer there

but then i had to log into my company from home using the solution suggested here [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)

```
git clone https://company-user-name:password@github.com/company-name/private-repo.git
```

and then i pushed normally and everything is fine

now i try to push work to my public profile but i got

```
remote: Permission to my-user-name/public-repo.git denied to company-user-name.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/my-user-name/public-repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

but running `git config user.name` and `git config --global user.name` returns `my-user-name` same for email

i know that user `my-user-name:password@github.com` would fix it but i need to know why this error is showing and how to work with both accounts simultaneously there must be a solution because github made a local and a global user

Comment: to which repo did you apply this solution  "Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed" ?

Comment: to public repo under my account `my-user-name/public-repo.git`

Comment: please take a look into the configured remotes (git remote -v) if the corresponding git repository is defined in there including username.