# How to solve the requested URL returned error: 403 in git repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, pull-request, git-pull

I have multiple accounts in git I committed code three weeks back with this account. I'll unable to pull my code . I was getting    The requested 
URL returned error: 403
I'll try [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed/9575906#9575906)
 but I couldn't solved my error

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin
remote: Forbidden
fatal: unable to access 
'https://chantidurgam@bitbucket.org/chantidurgam/patanjali.git/': The requested 
URL returned error: 403
```

Completed with errors, see above.

Comment: [Credential Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+credential+manager)?

Comment: I have noticed that bitbucket sometimes takes up to 10 minutes before a newly added user to a repositiory can "pull", although it is already visible from the web interface. I'd advise anybody running into an unexpected 403 to give it some time before taking other steps.

Answer (score 37):

What needs to be checked before anything else is the `access level`, which should be set to `write`. This can happen if you were added to the repo by someone else, and they forgot to grant you the required permissions.

[image]

Comment: thx @armin, I was struggling for an hour, even I have changed my password as sometimes it was saying that my password is wrong. +1 for saving my day.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue when using the git cli and sourcetree - and doing the below solved it.

This is basically an auth issue and git had stored my creds for both bitbucket and github. All I had to do was delete those saved entries using sourcetree.

I am using SourceTree, so went to Tools -> Options -> Authentication

and under git saved passwords, I deleted them all.

This post can lead to other ways of doing the same as well.

[Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)

Comment: Yup deleting all saved passwords in SourceTree worked for me! Thanks! Been struggling with this issue for nearly an hour now lol

Answer (score 12):

**Hi guys I am getting Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead. remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.**

Problem solution step by step

Now we have need Token authentication requirements for Git operations becouse Github has made changes in password authentication for security purpose.

There are some you need follow to generate Personal access tokens.

> **direct link https://github.com/settings/tokens/new for create personal
> access token**

Step 1 - Open GitHub and **sign in** with your credentials.

Step 2 - Click on the **Setting** menu.

Step 3 - In Setting menu you click on **Developer Settings**, there are two option avaialable for OAuth apps and Personal access tokens.

Step 4 - We need to click on **Personal access token**
[image]

step 5 - click on the Generate new Token button.

[image]

[image]

Step 7 - After that generate new token. Copy that generated token and use this token to access git with username and token.

**Now Manage your credentials in system**

**For window user**

1.) Open Control Panel => User Accounts => Manage your credentials => Windows Credentials.

[image]

[image]

In password box paste your access token and click to save button and reference your desktop.

Now you can access git.

If you are access git in android studio, if ask for a password then add GitHub Personal access token instead of your password.

And if you want use android terminal then paste cammand in terminal

```
 git push  https://ghp_FVLWF8rjU4HdsfsdgqSCjzIZh71yoF5N@github.com/username/yourrep.git
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I solved mine.

1. Go to bitbucket and open the repository.
2. At the top right corner is a "clone button" [image: Bitbucket clone button]
3. Click the button and copy the url. It will look something like this: **git clone https://something@bitbucket.org/something/something.git**
4. Open your terminal for and type the following

```html
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://something@bitbucket.org/something/something.git
```

Then just do git push. 
Note: Git may prompt you to do this.

```html
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Do it. I did and mine works now.

Answer (score 9):

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

The above code worked for me. As @Kunal said, I think a reason I had this issue was as a result of saving my credentials a while back and this causing an auth issue now. I hope the code works, this stumped me for over an hour.

Answer (score 6):

Reset the git credentials:
If its ubuntu system:

**Unset the username and password**

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
git config --unset credential.helper
```

Open the .git-crendentials and remove existing username and password

`vim ~/.git-credentials`

`https://username:password@mygit.github.com` to `https://mygit.github.com`

Store git credentials again:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
git pull
```

If it is windows:

Go to  **Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager**
In under Generic Credentials, You can see the stored git passwords and remove it.
[image]

Comment: Well explained!

Answer (score 3):

I have tried all the above solutions but non of them worked for me. My repo. using a proxy setting that I haven't added, Later I found that and added like :

`git config http.proxy http://example.com`

And its started work for me.

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete last directory all of details or delete directory and create another.
2. Go to ControlPanel < User Accounts < Credential Manager < Windows Credential(Generic Credentials) remove github/gitlab credentials
3. run command `git config --global <Url> http://localhost:<remote vpn port>`

It's resolved

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you have problem when you want to push your project in your git hub account and final  error was 403-fatal-http-request-failed you sign in another account in your PC
you must deleted that for this you must follow this address:
⇒ Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager and remove past account in github
this address is useful for Windows system

Answer (score 1):

For me this turned out to be a problem with 2-factor authentication between my Linux client and the Bitbucket website. When I went to do a pull from my server I got asked for my User:Pass and upon entering that correctly it gave me a `The requested URL returned error: 403`.
I removed the 2-factor from Bitbucket and everything started working again.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, this sourcetree specific issue is fixed by changing the ssh client as OpenSSH as I was having the key at C:\Users\username\ .ssh\id_rsa

You can change it at Tools -> Options -> General tab -> SSH client configuration

Note: For Putty or Plink, the key should be at C:\Users\username\ .ssh\id_rsa.ppk

Answer (score 0):

First try:

1. delete any existing ssh key (/.ssh/id_rsa).
2. ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com" #generation of new ssh key
   Email github wali.
3. after ssh key generation.
4. eval $(ssh-agent -s) To start ssh agent
5. ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
6. clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   paste this into the ssh key section of github.
   Now pushing git

git init
git add .
git commit -m ""
git status To check for the files.
git remote add origin "url of the repo" This step only for the first time.
git push -u origin master This is used for the initial push. Otherwise use git push.
**If still not working---- *go to credential manager then windows credential and delete personel access token of github.***

Answer (score 0):

In your Bitbucket.org account, go into Repository menu > User and group access and change the permissions of your user to WRITE or ADMIN. Then try again in your git!

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved this issues in Bitbucket by add an *app password* from [here](https://bitbucket.org/account/admin/app-passwords)