# remote: Forbidden The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a repository called "Abc" in Bitbucket with three different Dev branches like Dev_1, Dev_2, Dev_3(All three developer are part of the team).

When Dev_1 or Dev_2 or Dev_3 want to push their code to their respective branch using
`git push origin Dev_1`
command. I am getting an error:

```
remote: Forbidden fatal: unable to access 'https://abdulsayeed27@bitbucket.org/dfe_team/dfe_repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

1.I tried config and set-url like command.
But not able to fix this issue.
2.password is also correct.

Comment: Why do devs have their own branch?

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/403-while-accessing-https-username-bitbucket-org-username-repo-slug-git-info-refs-321854562.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533318/how-to-solve-the-requested-url-returned-error-403-in-git-repository

Comment: Do you have 2FA enabled on your account? Do you have write access to that repo? Do you have any branch restrictions on those branches in that repo?

Comment: evolutionxbox , because 1.there are more than 2 developers in the team. We want to run PMD check @developer level. 2. All the developer will push their code to their respective branch and create a pull request to Team lead.

Comment: Jim Redmond, No all are fine. Actually, We are facing the problem because We have created groups for team e.g. Dev and QA and Admin, then we also had access level security as well. Now What we have done is (using free BitBucket version) removed that groups and directly made everyone as admin.