# Why do i get this error while pushing to my github repository

Tags: git, github, command-line, git-bash

I recently started using git bash command line on my window pc, am able to clone a repository but when i want to push, i get this error...

```
remote: Permission to ********/Calculator.git denied to AwesomeBaron.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/********/Calculator/': The 
requested URL returned error: 403
```

The repository is my own on github. please what can i do.

Comment: Looks like you didn't set the right credentials. If you just started, you probably have a free plan, and that means this repo is public (it is indeed), which explains why you were able to clone it.

Comment: what should i do please to either be able to push or resolve it. I'm kinda new 
 to it please

Comment: How can i set the right credentials please

Comment: Do you control the repo?

Comment: yes it's my repo.

Comment: @Baron does this repo exist in the `git server` you're pushing into? Let's say it's GitHub, does your profile own a repo named `Calculator`? And have you configured `git` correctly?

Comment: yes i have a project in github called calculator and hopefully installed git correctly because other git function are working only the git push is not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+requested+URL+returned+error%3A+403

Answer (score 0):

You may need to import that URL as a certificate into your Keystore, that is if your credentials are correct.

Comment: my credentials were not correct, updating it helped in resolving it

Answer (score 0):

So i finally resolved it. 
My credentials were not correct so i had to remove the old credentials and add new one.

For window users

1)Navigate to your window start up menu and type "credential manager"

2)Click on windows credentials and navigate to github.com under Genric Credentials

3)Remove the existing user details and close the page.

4)Try pushing to your github again and you will be prompted to input your new details, when you are done added your details, your push should be successful