# Unable to push the existing code to a new git repository

Tags: git, github

I have `git` repository from the project I have deleted the `.git` file. Now I have created a new git repository and tried to push the code into the new repo. To do that I have used the command

1. git init
2. git add .
3. git commit -m ""
4. git remote add origin https://github.com/xxxx/project-sp.git
5. git push -u origin master

For the 5th point, the got an error as

> > Permission to xxx/project-sp.git denied to xxxx. fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx/project-sp.git/': The requested URL
> >     returned error: 403

Then I have removed the git credentials from the Credential Manager and used the command `git pull` 
I got the message as

```
warning: no common commits
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From https://github.com/xxx/project-sp
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

What should I do to push the code to the new git repo. I'm very new to the git. How do I solve this issue?

Update: When I'm trying to use command `git push --set-upstream origin master` I'm getting an error as

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxx/project-sp.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Are you sure you have access to this repo? Have you tried to configure an RSA key?

Comment: yes, I have I have login when I have used the cmd `git push`. What is RSA key I'm new to git environment.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by following the documentation of git or bitbucket.Here is the doc link that worked for  [me](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/importing-code-from-an-existing-project-776640909.html)

Comment: I followed the same steps but I'm getting an error when I'm trying to push the got an error.

Comment: Have you followed the steps at "https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/"

Comment: yes At the point where we use git push origin i'm facing error. I have updated the question please look into it.

Comment: Kindly follow the steps at "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed"

Comment: Kindly update the url in your git config file and commit it with -f flag

Comment: Also you have to pull the remote work as well. Because
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally.