# Could not push local file into git branch

Tags: git, github

I want to push my local file to the branch i created but it shows error 403 permission denied:

```
$ git push -u origin ashwin
```

> remote: Permission to roonal/project.git denied to furba576.
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/roonal/project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: Look like you don't have permission to push your code, try to check your account permission

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+The+requested+URL+returned+error%3A+403

Answer (score 0):

- You cannot push to any repository for which you don't have permission.

  - You can get permission from the repository owner.