# how to fix the error 403 so that I can push

Tags: java, git, android-studio, github

```
Push failed                     Remote: Permission to londonappbrewery/Quizzler-Android.git denied to arijitpaul0405.                   unable to access 'https://github.com/londonappbrewery/Quizzler-Android.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I'm not able to push my commit on GitHub. But I have successfully commited it. I'm new to GitHub. How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have write access to the mentioned remote repository?

Comment: Do you (should you) have permission to push to that repository? If you cloned a repository from someone else, you may not simply push your commits to that repository. If it's someone else's repository and you want to contribute a change then the usual way would be by _pull-request_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible problems.

- You entered wrong login or/and password in `git push` command or in the credentials manager.
- You don't have write access to this repository.

Comment: I tried a lot and re checked my password and username but all is okay. Moreover I'm doing a course from Udemy and the course include this project which I'm getting the access and before that I have submitted 4 projects from through the same course after editing but failed to submit last 2 projects due to same problem

Comment: So the repo is created not by you?

Comment: Sorry, Commander Tvis. When I checked my course I saw that the projects which I submitted successfully under that I observed that those projects were said to be uploaded on github but those which failed were not at all told to submit. Anyways thanks for your help