# Git collaborator cannot push

Tags: github

I was included as a collaborator in a college's homework. When I perform a push I get this:

```
remote: Permission to somename/Sistema-Estatistica.git denied to diegowebuzz.
fatal: não foi possível acessar 'https://github.com/somename/Sistema-Estatistica.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Clone, pull works as expected!

When I perform a push, I am asked my username and password. I am sure I provide those correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added him to the organization on github? If yes, check for his permissions and give him all.