# Permission to github repo denied to user

Tags: github

I was recently trying to push to a new github repo, and encountered an error.

```
/path/to/repo$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to JamesCrowleyTech/Chat-App.git denied to JamesCrowleyTech.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/JamesCrowleyTech/Chat-App.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I thought this was very strange because I am signed in with the same account as always.

These are my config settings (I am using a personal access token).

```
/path/to/repo$ git config -l
user.name=JamesCrowleyTech
user.email=jamescrowley467@gmail.com
credential.username=JamesCrowleyTech
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://<myPersonalAccessToken>@github.com/JamesCrowleyTech/Chat-App.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pushing to Git returning Error Code 403 fatal: HTTP request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)

Comment: Given that you're using https and hence a PAT, the answer probably has to do with the permissions you've set *for* that PAT. Note that this is purely a GitHub issue: Git is not involved at all here.