# Permission to repository is denied

Tags: git, shell, authentication, oauth, repo

```
root@a8def63cbfdc:\~/alx-pre_course# git push  
remote: Permission to tenuvar/alx-pre_course.git denied to tenuvar.  
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/tenuvar/alx-pre_course.git/':The requested URL returned error: 403
```

What causes this error and how can I rectify it? I have tried to push and upload my file to the remote repository and it is giving me the error above.

Comment: Does the answer marked as best [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed) provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by looking up credentials manager on your windows, then selecting windows credentials and deleting the credentials relating to github.

After you have done that, try pushing to your repository again and it should prompt you with a login screen where you can log into an account with permission to that repository.

If the problem is persistent, you can check if the repo owner has given you permission to push to their repository.

Hope that helps :)