# github push not working when trying to push from local to remote repository

Tags: github

Im trying to push my code in github using git push -u origin ,git push -u origin
fatal: The current branch main has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

```
git push --set-upstream origin main
```

To have this happen automatically for branches without a tracking
upstream, see 'push.autoSetupRemote' in 'git help config'.

PS C:\Users\madhu\PycharmProjects\OrangeHRM_Guvi_ATProject_2> git push --set-upstream origin main
remote: Permission to Madhumathi-AutomationTesting/OrangeHRM_Guvi_ATProject_2.git denied to madevkishan.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Madhumathi-AutomationTesting/OrangeHRM_Guvi_ATProject_2.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed) answer your question?